# `tail -f` until text is seen

Tags: logs, tail

I've got a CI server with a command-line interface that allows me to remotely kick-off a job (`jenkins` CI server and the `jenkins-cli.jar` tool).

After I kick the job off I `tail -f` the log (sorry for the messy command):

```
ssh -t my-jenkins-host.com "tail -f \"/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$job_name/builds/\`ls -ltr /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$job_name/builds/ | grep '^l' | tail -n 1|awk '{print \$9}'\`/log\""
```

After the job successfully completes, usually after at least 5 minutes, I get the following line on the output:

```
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Is there a good way to stop tailing the log at this point? i.e. is there like a `tail_until 'some line' my-file.log` command?

***BONUS:*** extra credit if you can supply an answer that returns 0 when SUCCESS is matched, 1 when FAILURE is matched, and your solution works on mac! (which i believe is bsd based)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can pipe the `tail -f` into `sed`, telling it to quit when it sees the line you're searching for:

```
tail -f /path/to/file.log | sed '/^Finished: SUCCESS$/ q'
```

`sed` will output each line it processes by default, and exit after it sees that line. The `tail` process will stop when it tries to write the next line and sees its output pipe is broken

Comment: booh yea! perfect.  ...so by any chance is there a way to exit 0 if i match one thing (say 'SUCCESS') and 1 if i match something else (like maybe 'FAILURE')?

Comment: @aaronstacy If you're using GNU grep, the `q` command takes an optional exit code. So the `sed` command would be `sed '/^Finished: SUCCESS$/ q0; /^Finished: FAILURE$/ q1'`

Comment: This might not work if `Finished: SUCCESS` is the last line of output

Comment: @Michael Mrozek aaaand of course i'm not b/c i'm using friggin mac

Comment: Perfecet answer!

Comment: Can we add a timeout to this, like: "if its not read between 60 to 120 seconds, then abort the tail and give an error exit code in the shell" ?

Comment: @kiltek Use [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout)

Comment: This solution has a major flaw: in my case the log ends by the searched line. No more lines will be written so the process would stay stuck as tail has no way to break :(

Comment: This does print everything up to and including the desired line, but it seems that `tail` never actually exits and instead just hangs. I see this same behavior both on my Linux server (distro unknown) running Jenkins as well as on my development Mac.

Comment: @Phate see [make tail -f exit on a broken pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416162/44425) for why and when it works or doesn't

Answer (score 7):

```
tail -f my-file.log | grep -qx "Finished: SUCCESS"
```

`-q`, meaning quiet, quits as soon as it finds a match

`-x` makes `grep` match the whole line

For the second part, try

```
tail -f my-file.log | grep -m 1 "^Finished: " | grep -q "SUCCESS$"
```

`-m <number>` tells grep to stop after *number* matches

and the `grep -q` exit status will only be `0` if `SUCCESS` is found at the end of the line

If you want to see all the output, you can't use `grep -q`, but you can still do

```
tail -f my-file.log | grep -m 1 "^Finished: "
```

which does everything except set the exit status to 1 if `FAILURE` appears.

Comment: I used `grep` in my answer originally, but if he's using `tail -f` he probably wants to see the file output; `grep` isn't going to show all the intermediate lines

Answer (score 6):

I didn't like any of the answers here, so decided to roll my own.  This bash script meets all the criteria, and includes the BONUS for exit of 1 on failure.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r LOGLINE || [[ -n "$LOGLINE" ]]; do
    printf '%s\n' "$LOGLINE"
    [[ "${LOGLINE}" == "Finished: SUCCESS" ]] && exit 0
    [[ "${LOGLINE}" == "Finished: FAILURE" ]] && exit 1
done < <(timeout 300 tail -f my-file.log)
exit 3
```

Also included is a timeout feature, which will result in an exit code of 3.  If you don't have the timeout command on your system, grab the timeout.sh script from Anthony Thyssen:

https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/ (search for "Timeout:")

Per the comments below, I updated the log print to stop escape character expansion and included all the features of a standard 'read'.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511 for complete 'read' details.  The EOF check isn't required here, but is included for completeness.

Comment: Very nice. Consider using `while IFS= read -r LOGLINE` to prevent the shell performing whitespace splitting on the lines from `tail`.

Comment: @roaima: `read` doesn't split when there is only one variable (and it's not an array with `-a`), but you do need `-r` if the input data contains backslash. But if the input data contains backslash, then `echo "$var"` may also screw up depending on your shell and/or system, so better `printf '%s\n' "$line"`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/100397)

Comment: Thanks, this works great on MacOS too.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on @Mikel's answer with @Mrozek's comments (I would have replied on the comment but I think i don't have enough privileges yet)

```
tail -f my-file.log | tee >( grep -qx "Finished: SUCCESS" )
```

would allow you to use @Mikel's solution and still see the output on the screen

Comment: Can we add a timeout intervall to this, like: "if its not read between 60 to 120 seconds, then abort the tail and give an error exit code in the shell" ?

Comment: one can use timeout for this i.e. timeout 15 sh -c "tail -f my-file.log | tee >( grep -qx 'Finished: SUCCESS' )"

Answer (score 3):

You also try

```
 grep -q 'App Started' <(tail -f /var/log/app/app.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with `sed` and `grep` and their options, so I write mine `one with bash conditions`

```
tail -f screenlog.* | 
while IFS= read line; 
 do 
   echo $line; 
   if [[ $line == *Started\ Application* ]]; 
    then pkill tail; 
   fi; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a python script that *almost* does what i want (see caveats below):

```
import sys,re

def main():
    re_end = re.compile(sys.argv[1])
    re_fail = re.compile(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv) > 2 else None
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        if re_end.match(line):
            sys.exit(0)
        elif re_fail and re_fail.match(line):
            sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

caveats:

- the lines aren't printed as they come in... they're printed in groups... seems to be some buffering going on
- i'd have to install this as a script on my path or something, so it's inconvenient, and i'd prefer a slick one-liner :)

Comment: update: `tail` seems to do the same buffering, so i'm guessing it's not something that's worth trying to work around.