# Understanding "IFS= read -r line"

Tags: bash, shell-script

I obviously understand that one can add value to internal field separator variable. For example:

```
$ IFS=blah
$ echo "$IFS"
blah
$
```

I also understand that `read -r line` will save data from `stdin` to variable named `line`:

```
$ read -r line <<< blah
$ echo "$line"
blah
$
```

However, how can a command assign variable value? And does it first store data from `stdin` to variable `line` and then give value of `line` to `IFS`?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906

Answer (score 170, accepted):

In POSIX shells, `read`, without any option doesn't read a *line*, it reads *words* from a (possibly backslash-continued) line, where words are `$IFS` delimited and backslash can be used to escape the delimiters (or continue lines).

The generic syntax is:

```
read word1 word2... remaining_words
```

`read` reads stdin one byte at a time¹ until it finds an unescaped newline character (or end-of-input), splits that according to complex rules and stores the result of that splitting into `$word1`, `$word2`... `$remaining_words`.

For instance on an input like:

```
  <tab> foo bar\ baz   bl\ah   blah\
whatever whatever
```

and with the default value of `$IFS`, `read a b c` would assign:

- `$a` ⇐ `foo`
- `$b` ⇐ `bar baz`
- `$c` ⇐ `blah   blahwhatever whatever`

Now if passed only one argument, that doesn't become `read line`. It's still `read remaining_words`. Backslash processing is still done, IFS whitespace characters² are still removed from the beginning and end.

The `-r` option removes the backslash processing. So that same command above with `-r` would instead assign

- `$a` ⇐ `foo`
- `$b` ⇐ `bar\`
- `$c` ⇐ `baz   bl\ah   blah\`

Now, for the splitting part, it's important to realise that there are two classes of characters for `$IFS`: the IFS whitespace characters² (including space and tab (and newline, though here that doesn't matter unless you use -d), which also happen to be in the default value of `$IFS`) and the others. The treatment for those two classes of characters is different.

With `IFS=:` (`:` being not an IFS whitespace character), an input like `:foo::bar::` would be split into `""`, `"foo"`, `""`, `bar` and `""` (and an extra `""` with some implementations though that doesn't matter except for `read -a`). While if we replace that `:` with space, the splitting is done into only `foo` and `bar`. That is leading and trailing ones are ignored, and sequences of them are treated like one. There are additional rules when whitespace and non-whitespace characters are combined in `$IFS`. Some implementations can add/remove the special treatment by doubling the characters in IFS (`IFS=::` or `IFS='  '`).

So here, if we don't want the leading and trailing unescaped whitespace characters to be stripped, we need to remove those IFS white space characters from IFS.

Even with IFS-non-whitespace characters, if the input line contains one (and only one) of those characters and it's the last character in the line (like `IFS=: read -r word` on a input like `foo:`) with POSIX shells (not `zsh` nor some `pdksh` versions), that input is considered as one `foo` word because in those shells, the characters `$IFS` are considered as *terminators*, so `word` will contain `foo`, not `foo:`.

So, the canonical way to read one line of input with the `read` builtin is:

```
IFS= read -r line
```

(note that for most `read` implementations, that only works for text lines as the NUL character is not supported except in `zsh`).

Using `var=value cmd` syntax makes sure `IFS` is only set differently for the duration of that `cmd` command.

#### History note

The `read` builtin was introduced by the Bourne shell and was already to read *words*, not lines. There are a few important differences with modern POSIX shells.

The Bourne shell's `read` didn't support a `-r` option (which was introduced by the Korn shell), so there's no way to disable backslash processing other than pre-processing the input with something like `sed 's/\\/&&/g'` there.

The Bourne shell didn't have that notion of two classes of characters (which again was introduced by ksh). In the Bourne shell all characters undergo the same treatment as IFS whitespace characters do in ksh, that is `IFS=: read a b c` on an input like `foo::bar` would assign `bar` to `$b`, not the empty string.

In the Bourne shell, with:

```
var=value cmd
```

If `cmd` is a built-in (like `read` is), `var` remains set to `value` after `cmd` has finished. That's particularly critical with `$IFS` because in the Bourne shell, `$IFS` is used to split everything, not only the expansions. Also, if you remove the space character from `$IFS` in the Bourne shell, `"$@"` no longer works.

In the Bourne shell, redirecting a compound command causes it to run in a subshell (in the earliest versions, even things like `read var < file` or `exec 3< file; read var <&3` didn't work), so it was rare in the Bourne shell to use `read` for anything but user input on the terminal (where that line continuation handling made sense)

Some Unices (like HP/UX, there's also one in `util-linux`) still have a `line` command to read one line of input (that used to be a standard UNIX command up until [the Single UNIX Specification version 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/line.html)).

That's basically the same as `head -n 1` except that it reads one byte at a time to make sure it doesn't read more than one line. On those systems, you can do:

```
line=`line`
```

Of course, that means spawning a new process, execute a command and read its output through a pipe, so a lot less efficient than ksh's `IFS= read -r line`, but still a lot more intuitive.

---

<sup>¹ though on seekable input, some implementations can revert to reading by blocks and seek-back afterwards as an optimisation. ksh93 goes even further and remembers what was read and uses it for the next `read` invocation, though [that's currently broken](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/15)</sup>

<sup>² *IFS whitespace characters*, per POSIX being the characters classified as `[:space:]` in the locale and that happen to be in `$IFS` though in ksh88 (on which the POSIX specification is based) and in most shells, that's still limited to SPC, TAB and NL. The only POSIX compliant shell in that regard I found was `yash`. `ksh93` and `bash` (since 5.0) also include other whitespace (such as CR, FF, VT...), but limited to the single-byte ones (beware on some systems like Solaris, that includes the non-breaking-space which is single byte in some locales)</sup>

Comment: +1 Thanks for some useful insights of the different treatments on space/tab vs "others" in IFS in bash... I knew they were treated differently, but this explanation simplifies it all a lot. (And the insight between bash (and other posix shells) and the regular `sh` differences is usefull too to write portable scripts!)

Comment: At least for `bash-4.4.19`, `while read -r; do echo "'$REPLY'"; done` works as `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "'$line'"; done`.

Comment: This: "...that erroneous notion that read is the command to read a line..." leads me to think, that if using `read` to read a line is erroneous, there must be something else. What could that non-erroneous notion be? Or is that first statement technically correct, but in truth the non-erroneous notion is: "read is the command to read words from a line. Because it's so powerful, you can use it to read lines from a file by doing: `IFS= read -r line`"

Comment: If you write `IFS=$'\n'`, is that the same as `IFS=` but with the trailing `\n` stripped off the end of each line?

Comment: @shadowtalker, though you do sometimes see `IFS=$'\n' read -r line` being used here and there, it is pointless as `read -r line` reads the input up to a newline, but the newline is not included in what is read, so `read` could never split on newline on the result. So it's exactly  the same as `IFS= read -r line`. In any case, it's better than forgetting the `IFS=`. It could make sense if using  a different delimiter as supported with`-d` in some `read`  implementations. `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' record` would read a NUL delimited record and remove leading and trailing newlines in it.

Answer (score 29):

### The Theory

There are two concepts that are in play here :

- `IFS` is the Input Field Separator, which means the string read will be split based on the characters in `IFS`. On a command line, `IFS` is normally any whitespace characters, that's why the command line splits at spaces.
- Doing something like `VAR=value command` means "modify the environment of command so that `VAR` will have the value `value`". Basically, the command `command` will see `VAR` as having the value `value`, but any command executed after that will still see `VAR` as having its previous value. In other words, that variable will be modified only for that statement.

### In this case

So when doing `IFS= read -r line`, what you are doing is setting `IFS` to an empty string (no character will be used to split, therefore no splitting will occur) so that `read` will read the entire line and see it as one word that will be assigned to the `line` variable. The changes to `IFS` only affect that statement, so that any following commands won't be affected by the change.

### As a side note

While the command is correct and will work as intended, setting `IFS` in this case <s>is not</s> *might<sup>1</sup> not be* necessary. As written in the `bash` man page in the `read` builtin section :

> One  line  is read from the standard input [...] and the first word is assigned to the first name, the second word to the second name, and so on, **with leftover words and their intervening separators assigned to the last name**.  If there are fewer words read from the input stream than names, the remaining names are assigned empty values. The characters in `IFS` are used to split the line into words. [...]

Since you only have the `line` variable, every words will be assigned to it anyway, so **if you don't need any of the preceding and trailing whitespace characters**<sup>1</sup> you could just write `read -r line` and be done with it.

[1] Just as an example of how an `unset` or default `$IFS` value will cause `read` to regard leading/trailing [*IFS whitespace*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), you might try:

```
echo ' where are my spaces? ' | { 
    unset IFS
    read -r line
    printf %s\\n "$line"
} | sed -n l
```

Run it and you will see that the preceding and trailing characters won't survive if `IFS` is not unset. Furthermore, some strange things could happen if `$IFS` was to be modified somewhere earlier in the script.

Comment: `x=a; x=b echo $x` why $x is a?  according to your answer, it should be b!

Comment: x=b only _within_ the echo command (whether builtin or binary). The $x substitution is performed well before that, in the shell. For example perl sees the environment variable as set to b `x=a; x=b perl -e 'print $ENV{"x"}; print "\n"'` but will print a if the substitution is done at time of invocation of course! `x=a; x=b perl -e "print qq($x\n);"`

Answer (score 7):

You should read that statement in two parts, the first one clears the value of the IFS variable, i.e. is equivalent to the more readable `IFS=""`, the second one is reading the `line` variable from stdin, `read -r line`.

What is specific in this syntax is the IFS affectation is transcient and only valid for the `read` command.

<s>Unless I'm missing something, in that particular case clearing `IFS` has no effect though as whatever `IFS` is set to, the whole line will be read in the `line` variable. There would have been a change in behavior only in the case more than one variable had been passed as parameter to the `read` instruction.</s>

Edit:

The `-r` is there to allow input ending with `\` not to be processed specially, i.e. for the backslash to be included in the `line` variable and not as a continuation character to allow multi-line input.

```
$ read line; echo "[$line]"   
abc\
> def
[abcdef]
$ read -r line; echo "[$line]"  
abc\
[abc\]
```

Clearing IFS has the side effect of preventing read to trim potential leading and trailing space or tab characters, eg :

```
$ echo "   a b c   " | { IFS= read -r line; echo "[$line]" ; }   
[   a b c   ]
$ echo "   a b c   " | { read -r line; echo "[$line]" ; }     
[a b c]
```

Thanks to rici for pointing that difference.

Comment: What you're missing is that if IFS is not changed, `read -r line` will trim leading and trailing whitespace before assigning the input to the `line` variable.

Comment: @rici I was suspecting something like that but only checked IFS characters between words, not leading/trailing ones. Thanks for pointing that fact !

Comment: clearing IFS will also prevent the assignment of multiple variables (side effect). 
`IFS= read a b <<< 'aa bb' ; echo "-$a-$b-"` will show `-aa bb--`

Answer (score 1):

This is a [good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942/178335) from the shell grammar perspective:

> A simple command is a **sequence of optional variable assignments** followed by blank-separated **words and redirections**, and terminated by a control operator. The first word specifies the command to be executed, and is passed as argument zero. The remaining words are passed as arguments to the invoked command.

from [bash reference 3.7.4](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment):

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by **prefixing it with parameter assignments**, as described in Shell Parameters. **These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command**.

`IFS=""` is only seen by the command, which is `read` here. In other words, `IFS` doesn't change the value of `IFS` except for this line.