# Unix bash/ksh : Selection of first non space character from file from specific line

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ksh

I have file `file1.txt` whose contents are as follows:

```
Date List
-----------
    Quarter Date
         Year Date
             Month Date
```

Now I want to read the non space elements from each row of file and to write to a variable.
For example for row 2 variable should contain `Quarter Year` only after removing space.

I tried:

```
tail -1 file1.txt > variable1
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `awk '{$1=$1}1'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
variable1="$(< inputfile sed -n '3s/ *//p')"
```

- `variable1="$([...])"`: runs the command `[...]` in a subshell and assigns its output to the variable `$variable`
- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `sed`'s `stdin`
- `-n`: suppresses output

**`sed` command breakdown**:

- `3`: asserts to perform the following command only on the 3rd line of input
- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the search pattern
- `*`: matches zero or more  characters
- `/`: stops the search pattern / starts the replacement string
- `/`: stops the replacement string (hence actually replacing with nothing) / starts the modifiers
- `p`: prints only the lines where the substitution succeeded

Comment: hat's off great answer

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The caret is needed for cases such as the first line of the sample input, where if missing it will drop the first space / sequence of spaces later in the string.

Comment: No, ` *` matches the empty string, so it will always match at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nope, I'll take it back, I was thinking about ` +`. You're right, it'll be consumed.

Answer (score 5):

First read the desired line into a variable (line 3 in the example):

```
var=$(sed -n '3p' file1.txt)
```

The sed command prints (`p`) the 3rd line of the file. The strip the leading spaces using [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
echo "${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
```

The inner substitution means to remove everyting except the leading spaces. The outer substitution remove those spaces at the beginning of the line.

Output is:

```
Quarter Date
```

Comment: wow, interesting use of bash's pattern matching…

Comment: @chaos how to store this result into a variable

Comment: @Aman Just `var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"`

Answer (score 4):

`tail -1 file1.txt > variable1` writes to the file `variable1`.

Use command substitution (bash.info 3.5.4, POSIX sh) instead:

```
variable1="$(tail -1 file1.txt)"
```

Btw my version of tail from GNU in cygwin doesn't have the `-1` option. Instead, I use `sed`:

```
# EREGEX: Replace all whitespace at beginning of line
# NOTE: BSD sed uses a different flag to enable EREGEX, -E.
# EDIT: Dropped -r. \s is already included in BRE.
#       Thanks to kos for pointing that out.
# EDIT: Use POSIX [:space:] instead of Perl \s.
variable1="$(sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' < file1.txt)"
```

Combined with line selection:

```
# EDIT: limit the [s]ubstitude operation to the 4th line only, and
#       [p]rint directly from s.
variable1="$(sed -ne '4s/^[[:space:]]*//p' < file1.txt)"
```

Comment: The `-r` option is only available on GNU `sed` (as far as I know) and anyway you're not using it, so I think it's safe to drop, along with the `-e` option which is redundant. In any case the last command doesn't work.

Comment: @kos The `-e` option is just a matter of sed style. In the second code block, I have already mentioned that in BSD sed there is another flag for ERE.

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that by dropping it it'd have matched a wider number of standards right away. Also the `g` modifier would be safe to be dropped

Comment: `\s` is a (recent) GNUism. It won't work elsewhere. The standard equivalent is `[[:space:]]`. Note that you don't have to keep the history  of your answer in. It's OK to change your answer without keeping trace of the older versions.

Answer (score 3):

With `ksh`/`zsh`/`bash`:

```
IFS=' ' read -r variable < <(tail -n 1 file)
```

[`read` strips leading and trailing space characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184) if space is found in `IFS` (which it is by default along with tab and newline).

You can also do:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r variable <&3; do
  something with "$variable"
done 3< file
```

To process the file line by line ([though that's not usually the way to go in shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) with `$variable` holding the current line's content with leading and trailing space characters removed.