# "echo $IFS" does not return the value of IFS

Tags: bash

I have set the `IFS` to `x`, i.e `IFS=x`. Now if I check the value of `IFS`, then it appears to be empty if I do not use double-quotes:

```
~ $ echo $IFS | cat -e
$
~ $ echo "$IFS" | cat -e
x$
~ $ echo $HOME   
/home/mar
~ $ echo "$HOME"
/home/mar
~ $
```

As seen above, `$HOME` does not behave like that. What is the reason for such behavior?

Answer (score 9):

After the variable is expanded, word-splitting occurs and it gets split into empty word(s). Splitting is done using each character of the `IFS` variable as delimiter and since `$IFS` only expands to characters in the `IFS` it gets split into empty word(s).

So, for example:

```
IFS=xxx;
printf %q $IFS
''''''[root@localhost ~]#
```

And if you double quote, you are telling bash to treat everything inside the quotes as one word:

```
printf %q "$IFS"
xxx[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: As I understand, if I use single- or double-quotes around the argument for `echo`, then there is no word-splitting and this single argument is passed to `echo`. So am I correct that if I don't use double-quotes around the variable name then word-splitting based on characters in `IFS` variable take place?

Comment: You are correct, but not single quotes, if you use single quotes: `echo '$IFS'` result will be `$IFS`.

Comment: I see, thanks! However, how should one understand word-splitting? I mean if I execute examples like `IFS="blah" echo $IFS` or `IFS=x VAR="abcxklm" echo $VAR` or `IFS=x VAR="abcx" echo $VAR | sed -n l` then I would think that word-splitting is substituting characters in expanded variable with space if `IFS` character(s) is in the middle of the string and with nothing if no other characters follow?

Comment: you can test simple word-splitting with this: `list="koko moko"` and then `for i in $list` and `for i in "$list"` will produce different results.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's related to what's stated in [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

> Use double quotes to prevent word splitting. [2] An argument enclosed
>   in double quotes presents itself as a single word, even if it contains
>   whitespace separators.

With the examples (5.1):

```
var="'(]\\{}\$\""
echo $var        # '(]\{}$"
echo "$var"      # '(]\{}$"     Doesn't make a difference.

IFS='\'
echo $var        # '(] {}$"     \ converted to space. Why?
echo "$var"      # '(]\{}$"
```

Comment: The reason why "\" becomes " " is explained in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/27616 (by @StéphaneChazelas ) ( "\" became an IFS, an Input Field Separator, so `$var` now contains 2 "parts", one before "\", the other after "\". And those  2 parts are written one after the other, separated by a space

Answer (score 0):

Another way to work around the word splitting issue here is:

```
set | grep -w IFS=
```

which outputs the default IFS as

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

See this related post on Stack Overflow:

- [Can IFS be changed locally in a Bash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50728845/6862601)