# "while read" also output things that aren't read/edited

Tags: shell, text-processing

What I want to do is edit an xml file, and replace something that is inside one of the tags. This is my script:

```
while read line; do
if [[ "$line" == *"<Valuec=\"0\">"* ]]
then 
~/bin/nn4 Decrypt1 "$line" | sed 's/^/\<Valuec=\"0\"\>/g;s/$/\<\/Valuec\>/g'
fi
done <"$1"
```

`nn4` removes the tags, decrypts the contents and the `sed` command puts the tags back.

Here is the input

```
<string>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <file>file.txt</file>
    <Valuec="0">982498as9adhfsdf</Valuec>
</string>
<string>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <strStringCaption>file2.txt</strStringCaption>
    <Valuec="0">2389aHASDasd</Valuec>
</string>
```

However, this, ofcourse, only outputs the lines that are edited. It looks something like this:

```
<Valuec="0">decryptedstring</Valuec>
<Valuec="0">decryptedstring2</Valuec>
```

However, I want it to look like this:

```
<string>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <file>file.txt</file>
    <Valuec="0">decryptedstring</Valuec>
</string>
<string>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <strStringCaption>file2.txt</strStringCaption>
    <Valuec="0">decryptedstring2</Valuec>
</string>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `else` condition to your body of `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
if [[ "$line" == *"<Valuec=\"0\">"* ]]
then 
  ~/bin/nn4 Decrypt1 "$line" | sed 's/^/\<Valuec=\"0\"\>/g;s/$/\<\/Valuec\>/g'
else
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
fi
done <"$1"
```

Note the use of [`IFS= read -r` to completely read a *line*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/38906).

Anyway, you should consider to use other the tools for this task. [Using while loop in shell script is considered bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906).