# Keep \ in read variable to show space

Tags: shell, read

Trying to keep spaces in the variable for read with the `\`.

```
$ echo "Drag folder to be copied to terminal and press ENTER."
$ read FILE
/Users/UserName/Desktop/Folder\ With\ Spaces\ In\ it
$ echo "$FILE"
/Users/UserName/Desktop/Folder With Spaces In it
```

The `\` have been removed. I need them to remain as it will be used later in copy. Example.

```
$ cp -R $FILE /Volumes/USBName
```

I have played with different quotation marks and looked around but nothing has worked for me so far. I may have to change the IFS, not sure?

Comment: `cp -R "$FILE" …`, same as when you used `echo`

Comment: @Gilles I agree that's a dupe of the question that *should* have been asked: but isn't the answer to the question *actually* asked `read -r`?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/38906

Comment: @steeldriver Not with the example given (`cp -R "$FILE"` needs to have a variable with no spurious backslashes — whereas `cp -R $FILE` would require more than backslashes to work reliably), but even if it was, the duplicate also discusses `read -r`.

Comment: The `echo` was just to check.