# Find command - argument list too long

Tags: shell-script, find

Oracle Linux 5.10
BASH shell

```
[oracle@src01]$ getconf ARG_MAX
131072

[oracle@srv01]$ ls -1 | wc -l
40496

#!/bin/bash
#
# delete files in /imr_report_repo that are older than 15-days
find /imr_report_repo/* -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +15 |
while read file
do
    rm -f $file 
done

/usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

If I'm reading this right the maximum arguments allowed is 131,072 and I only have 40,496 files in this directory. I haven't checked, but I'm probably trying to delete 40,000 files (over 2-weeks old).

Comment: We're talking about the maximum _length_ of the command line argument (128K in this case)... Remove the `*` (why would you need that ?) and retry. I'm not sure why you need the `while..read` loop either...

Comment: @don_crissti is right.  in other words: `find /imr_report_repo/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} +`.  or if you're trying to delete files in immediate sub-directories of `/imr_report_repo/` (but not /imr_report_repo itself) then use `find /imr_report_repo/*/ -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +15  -exec rm {} +` - note the trailing `/` (but note also that this is also subject to ARG_MAX limit of 128Kbytes).

Comment: @cas Thanks! Please consider moving your comment to an answer.

Comment: Is the `-delete` option not available in your `find`?

Comment: @Fiximan -delete is available, but we have other systems where it is not available. Keeping portability in mind

Comment: In that case you'll have to remove the `maxdepth` because it's only available where/when `delete` is available too...

Answer (score 20):

I think this has been answered here:

https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1136262

The shell is doing a file expansion of /imr_report_repo/* , which causes the problem.  I had a similar issue which I fixed by changing the find command from

```
find /imr_report_repo/* -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +15
```

to

```
find /imr_report_repo/ -name "*" -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +15
```

The quotes keep the shell from expanding the wildcard and then find can use it as a regular expression.  It also helps if you need to search for a large number of files that match a specific criteria (like "*.foo").

Answer (score 1):

The maximum command line length is the total size in bytes, not the number of arguments. 40k files with names of the form `/imr_report_repo/*` means a minimum of about 800kB, probably more. That's over the limit.

The obvious solution is to make `find` do the recursion for you. Go from depth 1 to depth 1 instead of depth 0 to depth 0.

```
find /imr_report_repo/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +15 -delete
```

Unlike the original, this includes files whose name begins with `.` (dot files). If you don't want that, exclude them:

```
find /imr_report_repo/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -prune -o -type f -mtime +15 -delete
```

Most `find` implementations that have `-maxdepth` also have `-delete`. If yours doesn't, don't just pipe the result into `while read`: it's somewhat slow and breaks on file names containing newlines (and backslashes and trailing whitespace because you used `read` where you [should have used `IFS= read -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line)). Use `-exec`, that's what it's for.

```
find /imr_report_repo/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm -f {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `find /imr_report_repo/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} +` or, as suggested by @Fiximan, `find /imr_report_repo/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +15 -delete`

If you're trying to delete files in immediate sub-directories of /imr_report_repo/ (but not /imr_report_repo itself) then use `find /imr_report_repo/*/ -maxdepth 0 -type f -mtime +15 -exec rm {} +` (or `... -delete`) - note the trailing `/`

note also that this is also subject to ARG_MAX limit of 128Kbytes.