# How can I check that two input values are correct in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am writing a bash script and want to add some simple validation tests. The input should be either `1` or `2` and the script should ask for input again until the correct input is given.

I was thinking of doing this using an `until` loop but it didn't work. I tied `until [ $group -eq 1 ]` (where `$group` is the value given by the user) but obviously I also need a 2nd input. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Show your code

Comment: We can't help if you don't show i) the _exact_ code you used, what you show is a syntax error and ii) the error message you received. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I edited it to make it clearer. I was hoping the OP would do so instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
until
  printf 'Please enter 1 or 2: '
  IFS= read -r line || exit # exit on EOF
  [ "$line" = 1 ] || [ "$line" = 2 ]
do
  printf >&2 '"%s" is neither 1 nor 2, try again.\n' "$line"
done
```

With `IFS=` and `-r`, the input line is stored as-is in `$line`. You may want to omit the `IFS=` so that blanks (assuming you've not modified `$IFS`) are automatically stripped from the beginning or end of the input.

If the input has to be the `1` or `2` strings only, then you want to use `=`, not `-eq`.

If you want to allow other expressions of the `1` or `2` *numbers*, like `01`, `1+1`, `1.0`, `100e-2`, `exp(0)`, `RANDOM` (sometimes), then you could use `-eq`, but note that not all shells accept all types of expressions above (`ksh93` will accept them all, but `bash` would only accept things like   `1`  (leading and/or trailing blanks), or `0001` (leading zeros)), and that means you'll get error messages for inputs that don't form valid arithmetic expressions.

With shells that interpret arithmetic expressions, that's also dangerous as that can change variable values (like for an input like `PATH=123`) or even run arbitrary commands (like for inputs like `a[0$(cmd>&2)]`).

Depending on the shell, you could also get false positives on 18446744073709551617 or 4294967297 (or any other multiple of 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> + 1 or 2) as most shells use 64bit or 32bit integer numbers.

Whatever you do, do **not** use the `-o` and `-a` binary `test`/`[` operators. Those should be banished as [they make the parsing of the `[` command potentially ambiguous and in practice unreliable (and are now marked *obsolete* in the POSIX spec)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16).

For instance:

```
$ line='!' sh -c '[ "$line" = 1 -o "$line" = 2 ]'
sh: line 0: [: too many arguments
```

And remember to quote your variables (`"$line"`, not `$line` which would undergo split+glob).

Comment: When you say *With `IFS=` and `-r`, the input line is stored as-is in `$line`* -  What is the need to store as-is? Even if the line was split into words delimited by `IFS` won't read dump all the words into `$line` anyway? (because `line` is the only variable available)

Comment: @the_velour_fog, see [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184)

Answer (score 1):

This should work, combine them with or (`-o`):

```
#init group variable
group=0
#read until value is either 1 or 2
until [ $group -eq 1 -o $group -eq 2 ]; 
    do 
    #your script...

    #read user input and put it in group
    read -p "Which group?" group 
done
```

You can also use `||` as or operator:

```
until [ $group -eq 1 ] || [ $group -eq 2 ]
```

Although in some cases, for example when you use the error code (`$?`) the first options is better, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30164389/1771479).

Comment: With the default value of IFS, that would accept inputs like `1 -o 1` or `! 0`. I can't think of any reason why you would want to invoke the split+glob operator here.

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r; do
    case "$REPLY" in
        1|2) break ;;
        *)   echo 'Error' >&2 ;;
    esac
done
```

This code snipped reads a value from standard input and then tests it against `1` and `2`.  If matching either string, the loop exits, otherwise a terse diagnostic message is produced and the loop continues.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the second condition to the expression using the *or* operator `-o`.

Comment: `-o` and `-a` `[` binary operators should be avoided, they make the parsing of the `[` command potentially ambiguous and in practice unreliable. Use `[ "$i" = 1 ] || [ "$i" = 2 ]` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can you provide any sources for this claim? While your alternative seems to be valid, I consider it a solution to a problem most people don't have...

Comment: See link in my answer.

Comment: @Murphy: `[ "!" = 1 -o 1 = 1 ]` raise error in most shells except `zsh`.

Comment: @cuonglm I think that should go to Stéphane, shouldn't it? The OP was using the correct numerical operator, and I didn't advise against it.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Well, it is an incomplete answer to an incomplete question, but as far as I can see it's technically correct and a solution to the problem. Does this justify deletion?

Comment: The answer to my previous comment seems to be here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244987/recommend-deletion-needs-another-type-for-low-quality-posts

Comment: @Murphy Technically, The correct description is to add the second test as this: `[ "$group" = 1 ] || [ "$group" = 2 ]` the -o or -a binary operators are [Marked obsolete in the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16). But that is just secondary. The same way as I can make a comment with all this information, you could have given your point of view in a comment. The text of this answer is quite small (and, as you say, incomplete).

Comment: @cuonglm the correct syntax is: `[ ! 0 = 1 -o 1 = 1 ]` if you want to negate a test of `0 = 1` or `[ 'x!' = 'x1' -o 1 = 1 ]` if you want to use the `!` as text and both work in most shells.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Of course, the purpose of example to show how weird `-o/-a` can be.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you very much for the update, I just added this to our knowledge base and will strive to apply it for new scripts. The [Linux manpages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) aren't updated yet, I will send a notice to MTK/linux-man.

Comment: @Murphy, that's not a Linux manpage as maintained by mtk, that man page is maintained within coreutils (as a short description derived from the help message of GNU `test`). The info page has the manual for GNU `test`, and it does say there to avoid -a and -o. In anycase, `test`/`[` is built in all modern Bourne-like shells, so it's not GNU `test` you invoke when you call `[` or `test` in a Bourne-like shell script.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, can then be assumed that the bash builtins suffer from the same problem? However, the mail is already on the way, let's see what comes out of that.

Comment: http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=22909