# How shrink test -eq expression with more than one var value in /bin/sh

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $num -eq 9 -o $num -eq 75 -o $num -eq 200 ]; then
    echo "do this"
elif [ $num -eq 40 -o $num -eq 53 -o $num -eq 63]; then
    echo "do something for this"
else
    echo "for other do this"
fi
```

Is any other way to the shrink the expression in the `if` statement? 
Perhaps something like

```
[ $num -eq (9,75,200) ]
```

BTW, I don't have GNU utils on this OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes a different construction may end up more readable:

```
case $num in
9|75|200) echo "do this" ;;
40|53|63) echo "do something for this" ;;
*)        echo "for other do this" ;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there any case where this could fail where the `-eq` test would succeed?  How does `-eq` handle something like `9.0`?

Comment: @Wildcard As you note, `case` is just doing string compare whereas `-eq` is doing an arithmetic compare, so the former will fail for num=010 compared with 10, whereas the latter will compare equal. Only integers are  allowed though.

Comment: @Wildcard Get rid of the decimal part before calling `case`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89712/bash-float-to-integer

Comment: @Wildcard, that depends a lot on the `sh`/`[` implementation, see [How can I check that two input values are correct in a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267340)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a job for a function:

```
test_num() {
  n=$1; shift
  for arg do
    [ "$arg" -eq "$n" ] && return 0
  done
} 2>/dev/null

if test_num "$num" 9 75 200; then
  echo "do this"
elif test_num "$num" 40 53 63; then
  echo "do something for this"
else
  echo "for other do this"
fi
```

Comment: Just interesting, nothing wrong. This is four times slower than the case option.  Twice slower than the `^(...)` option.

Comment: The `n=$1 shift` might fail to set `$n` for following statements.

Comment: To avoid the `2>/dev/null` you may think of using `=` instead of `-eq`.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos: you don't need. If nothing equal to $n, status of last test return, which is fail

Comment: @cuonglm This fail: `[ "" -eq "" ]; echo $?`

Comment: @cuonglm As will any of the next a values in `[ "$a" -eq "$num" ]`: `0+1`, `1e2`, `1.0`, `1.3`, `1,0`, `-+1`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

careful, posix doesn't define test with more than 4 arguments, so your test construct is **undefined**.  see the [6th bash pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D)

So you would need, if using test, to be more verbose:

```
if [ "$arg" = 9 ] || [ "$arg" = 75 ] || [ "$arg" = 200 ]
```

or use case instead

```
case "$arg" in
     9|75|200)  do something ; ;
     40|53|63)  do that ;;
      *)  else ... ;;
 esac
```

Comment: I tested with /bin/sh of ksh88, 6 argument working fine: `if [ $num -eq 9 -o $num -eq 75 -o $num -eq 200  -o $num -eq 13 -o $num -eq 58 -o $num -eq 14]; then echo "do this"; fi`

Comment: @ragnarLodbrog: Posix should be followed. I didn't mean it will fail everywhere and anytime. But you can't rely on this, and could have problems if you do... Maybe some other cases would fail (and some other environment could fail on that one).

Comment: Actually POSIX is silent on the issue.  The four arguments issue is only mentioned in non-normative text.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh` (and maybe some others, i can't recall right now) you could use `[[ ... ]]` rather then `[ ... ]`, which allows you to do regular expression matches in sh.

e.g.

```
if [[ "$num" =~ ^(9|75|200)$ ]] ; then
    echo "do this"
elif [[ "$num" =~ ^(40|53|63)$ ]] ; then
    echo "do something for this"
else
    echo "for other do this"
fi
```

NOTE: because you want an exact match on the specific numbers, it's important that the regex is anchored at both ends with `^`and `$`, otherwise they'll match other numbers that contain them (e.g. '99' or '7500' or '163')

Comment: Well, this is non-standard and thus non-portable and it appears to be more complex than the case based solution.

Comment: sorry to trigger your rabidly self-righteous anti-GNUism but this `=~` operator came from `ksh` and was adopted by `bash`, so you've wasted an anti-GNU rant opportunity on a false alarm.  BTW, whether an answer is 'complex' or not is irrelevant...and I did point out that it only works in certain shells.

Comment: This is great example `=~` working on linux, but not in my unix system. So sad. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that while `[[...]]` comes from `ksh`, the `=~` operator within it was first introduced by bash AFAIK (though `zsh` had a `-pcre-match` `[[...]]` operator before that).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas thank you for pointing to `ksh` and BTW: the `bash` manual from September 2006 does not mention `=~` but `ksh93` documents that the feature was added in May 2006. So this feature seems to be from `ksh93` as well. @cas: personal attacks do not work well, if done by uninformed people ;-) `[[` is from `ksh88` and thus is older than `bash`.

Comment: @schily, `=~` was added in bash 3.0 in 2004. `zsh`'s ` `pcre` module was introduced in 2001 though the `-pcre-match` operator was only added in 2004

Answer (score 0):

An alternative POSIX solution:

```
if     printf '%s' "$num" | grep -xE '(9|75|200)' >/dev/null; then
       echo "do this"
elif   printf '%s' "$num" | grep -xE '(40|53|63)' >/dev/null; then
       echo "do something for this"
else
       echo "for other do this" 
fi
```

This is awfully slow ~50 times slower than the `case` option.

---

This is a shorter and I believe a simpler script, only twice the time of the case option:

```
#!/bin/sh

num="$1"    a='9 75 200'    b='40 53 63'

tnum() {
    for    arg
    do     [ "$arg" = "$num" ] && return 0
    done   return 1
}

if     tnum $a; then
            echo "do this"
elif   tnum $b; then
            echo "do something for this"
else
            echo "for other do this"
fi
```

CAVEAT: No test `[ "$arg" = "$num" ]` will work in all cases, this fails on `00 = 0` for example.
And a numerical test `[ "$arg" -eq "$num" ]` will fail to match empty values `[ "" -eq "" ]`.

You may choose what works better in your case.

Comment: I can't use bash, it is POSIX unix OS

Comment: @RagnarLodbrog Changed to a POSIX solution.

Comment: Changing the logic to compare string instead of integer can cause false positive, e.g `[ 00 = 0 ]` compare to `[ 00 -eq 0 ]`.

Comment: That's why 2>/dev/null was used

Comment: @cuonglm What Change? My answer aims to have shorter tests: `tnum $a`, which it does very well.