# Is `var=value builtin` the same as `var=value; builtin`?

Tags: shell, posix

In [my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267996/38906), I used the construct:

```
n=$1 shift
```

Reading [Token Recognition spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03), I understand that the shell will parse that line into two parts - the variable assignment `n=$1` and the builtin command `shift`.

But [the comments on my answer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36611/discussion-between-binaryzebra-and-cuonglm) state that `n=$1 shift` does fail in some shells.

I spawned a quick check:

```
$ for shell in /bin/*[^c]sh; do
  printf '=%-17s=\n' "$shell"
  "$shell" -c 'a=$1 shift; echo "$a"' "$shell" 1
done
=/bin/ash         =
1
=/bin/bash        =

=/bin/dash        =
1
=/bin/heirloom-sh =
1
=/bin/ksh         =
1
=/bin/lksh        =
1
=/bin/mksh        =
1
=/bin/pdksh       =
1
=/bin/posh        =
1
=/bin/schily-osh  =
1
=/bin/schily-sh   =
1
=/bin/yash        =
1
=/bin/zsh         =
```

All shells, except `bash` and `zsh`, worked. But `bash` in `posix` mode and `zsh` in `sh` emulation do work, too:

```
$ ARGV0=sh bash -c 'a=$1 shift; echo "$a"' sh 1
1
$ ARGV0=sh zsh -c 'a=$1 shift; echo "$a"' sh 1 
1
```

Using `var=value; shift` worked in all shells.

So, are those constructs the same in POSIX-compliant shells?

Comment: `shift` might be a special case. Try another builtin eg `a=$1 let x=99;...`, or a real command. (I remember many years ago having to go through all my scripts putting `;` before `shift` when I first moved to bash).

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate of the other named question.

Comment: See my recent answer for the other question that was incorrectly set up as duplicate to understand why both questions are completely different. If someone removes the duplicate tag, I could give a correct answer for this question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Bourne Shell, variable assignments before any kind of builtin command affects the whole shell.

As David Korn started to create an enhanced Bourne Shell with many builtins before he added history editing, it may have been obvious for him that this behavior is a problem.

As a result, ksh88 behaves different and this behavior has become the master for the newer POSIX standards.

The current rule is:

- `VAR=value` before a `special builtin` affects the whole shell
- `VAR=value` before any other commands only affect this command even in case this is a builtin command.

Your mistake was to run your tests with a `special builtin`.

If you like to get a list of special builtins, you may e.g. call `builtin -s` in the `Schily Bourne Shell`.

If you did your tests with a different builtin, e.g. with the `cd` command, you would have seen different results, as the variable assignment would only survive the `cd` command if the test was run on a classic Bourne Shell.

Note however that POSIX permits but does not require a shell to keep the environment with `special builtins`. If you like to get the same behavior for all builtins (even special builtins), you may prepend the name of the builtin by `command`.

Comment: As I interpreted, your answer is the same as what @Gilles said in other question.

Comment: It may be that this was amongst the long answer, but isn't is nice to answer a question with as few words as possible and the answer from @Gilles in the other question was not related to the other question.