# Bash while loop read from colon-delimited list of paths using IFS

Tags: bash, shell, string

I am trying to write a bash function that behaves similarly to the `where` builtin in `tcsh`. In `tcsh`, `where` lists all the builtins, aliases, and the absolute paths to executables on the `PATH` with a given name, even if they are shadowed, e.g.

```
tcsh> where tcsh
/usr/bin/tcsh
/bin/tcsh
```

As part of this I want to loop over everything in the `$PATH` and see if an executable file with the appropriate name exists.

The following bash snippet is intended to loop over a colon-delimited list of paths and print each component followed by a newline, however, it just seems to print the entire contents of `$PATH` all on one line

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=':' read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done <<< "$PATH"
```

As is stands now, `bash where` and `./where` just print `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

So, how do I set up my while loop so that the value of the loop variable is each segment of the colon-separated list of paths in turn?

Comment: Why not use `type -a`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas because I didn't know it existed. :/

Comment: See also [Debian's `which` script](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/users/clint/debianutils.git/tree/which) for how to loop over `$PATH` properly.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see so if you use `IFS=':' ; for x in $PATH ; do echo "$x" ; done`, then the loop variable will be set to each element of `$PATH` in turn. Why do the `for` and `while` loop treat `IFS` differently?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet it's not `while` that's doing anything with `IFS` in this case, it's `read`, which reads a *whole* line at once, regardless of `IFS`—as [Stephane explained](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276620/135943), actually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`read` uses `IFS` to separate the words in the line it reads, it doesn't tell `read` to read until the first occurrence of any of the characters in it.

```
IFS=: read -r a b
```

Would read one line, put the part before the first `:` in `$a`, and the rest in `$b`.

```
IFS=: read -r a
```

would put the whole line (the rest) in `$a` (except if that line contains only one `:` and it's the last character on the line).

If you wanted to read until the first `:`, you'd use `read -d:` instead (`ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash` only).

```
printf %s "$PATH" | while IFS= read -rd: dir || [ -n "$dir" ]; do
  ...
done
```

(we're not using `<<<` as that adds an extra newline character).

Or you could use standard word splitting:

```
IFS=:; set -o noglob
for dir in $PATH""; do
  ...
done
```

Now beware of few caveats:

- An empty `$PATH` component means the current directory.
- An empty `$PATH` means the current directory (that is, `$PATH` contains one component which is the current directory, so the `while read -d:` loop would be wrong in that case).
- `//file` is not necessary the same as `/file` on some system, so if `$PATH` contains `/`, you need to be careful with things like `$dir/$file`.
- An *unset* $PATH means a *default* search path is to be used, it's not the same as a set but empty $PATH.

Now, if it's only the equivalent of `tcsh`/`zsh`'s `where` command, you could use `bash`'s `type -a`.

More reading:

- [What's a safe and portable way to split a string in shell programming?](/a/64173)
- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)
- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)

Answer (score 4):

[**Don't use shell loops to process text.**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Instead, use `awk`, or `tr`, or even `sed`.

```
printf %s\\n "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'

printf %s "$PATH" | awk 'BEGIN {RS=":"}; 1'
```

Or, since this is a shell variable you are processing, just use `bash` pattern substitution:

```
echo "${PATH//:/
}"
```

(See `LESS=+/parameter/pattern man bash`.)

Comment: Why the downvote?  I see three other answers have been given downvotes just now with no comments...why?

Answer (score 1):

Pure `bash`, it's the same thing as [*Wildcard*'s 2nd method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276616/165517), but this is on one line:

```
echo -e "${PATH//:/"\n"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This script works similar to the command `where`

```
#!/bin/bash
fn="foo"
for i in `echo $PATH|tr ':' '\n'`
do
  if [[ -e "$i/$fn" ]] ; then
    echo $i
  fi
done
```

`$fn` is something you want to find.

`$i/$fn` may be `$i$fn` sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Shell utils:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```