# Unix for loop not working

Tags: scripting, for

I've a simple bash script. PFB :

```
CWD=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
cd $CWD
for i in `cat req_files.txt`
do
echo "file_found : $i">a.txt
done
```

Note : req_files.txt is having a list of files which i need to find in this directory . If the files are found, it should list the name of the file which was found & print it in "a.txt".

The req_files.txt is having multiple files,but only the first filename is getting printed & not the rest of the files. Pl help.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be overwriting the contents of a.txt each time round the loop.

```
echo "file_found : $i">a.txt
```

Should replace `>` with `>>`.

Or place it after the done to avoid opening and closing it each time. Adding this to the other answer to give

```
done < req_files.txt > a.txt
```

I've left it as just open not append as it doesn't need to save anything from what's shown so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from file which lines contain spaces/tabs/etc you have to use `while` loop instead of `for`

```
CWD=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
cd $CWD
while read i
do
echo "file_found : $i">a.txt
done < req_files.txt
```

Comment: Note that this still overwrites the output file in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not contain lines to search in the given directory and compare the files inside that directory with the given files (req_files.txt). All you do is keep on overwriting (since you are using `>` operator, use `>>` to append instead) the file a.txt with contents of req_files.txt one by one and when the script finishes running, you are left with only the last item written to a.txt.

As per my understanding, your goal is:

Search and list all the files inside that given path. Then compare that list with the files listed in req_files.txt. And finally, list the matching ones in the output file a.txt. In that case, below code does it for you:

```
cwd=/cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder
cd $cwd #change dir to the required path
>a.txt  # create output file a.txt
for file in `ls`:
do
        grep "`echo "$file"`" req_files.txt >> a.txt
done
```

In for loop, you are now listing the files using ls command. This script will create a file a.txt inside the given path which contains the files from req_files.txt that are present in that given path.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection operator needs to be replaced with concatenation

```
echo "file_found : $i" >> a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You are truncating (emptying) the output file in each iteration of your loop.

You are also looping over the output of `cat`, which is dangerous as the shell will split the output on spaces, tabs and newlines (by default) and also perform filename globbing on the result.  If a line says `*`, it will be replaced by all the filenames in the current directory.

Instead:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/abhisek.samanta/Desktop/New_folder || exit 1

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf 'File found: %s\n' "$line"
done <req_files.txt >a.txt
```

This would read from the file `req_files.txt` and write the output of the loop into `a.txt`.  The file `a.txt` would be truncated before output is written to it.  If it does not exist, it will be created.

Would you want to *append* the output to an already existing file, use `>>` rather than `>`.

See also:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)