# How to read different lines of a file to different variables?

Tags: bash

I would like to read different lines of a text file to different variables. For example

`input.txt`:

```
line1 foo foobar bar
line2 bar
line3 foo
line4 foobar bar
```

I want this result to be stored in variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `var4` such that

```
var1=line1 foo foobar bar
var2=line2 bar
```

and so on.

Could someone please tell me how it is done. I tried to use `eval` in a for loop. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: This is a bad approach.  Since basically the only reason to set variables is to *do something with them,* and since there are a vast number of tools specifically *designed* to do things with every line of text in a file (Awk, Sed, `grep`, `cut`, et. al.), it's much much better to just **do** what you need to do.  Don't micromanage in a shell script; orchestrate tools to get the job done.

Answer (score 21):

You'd do:

```
unset -v line1 line2
{ IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2; } < input.txt
```

Or:

```
{ line1=$(line) && line2=$(line); } < input.txt
```

(less efficient as `line` is rarely built-in and most shells need to fork to implement command substitution. `line` is also no longer a standard command).

To use a loop:

```
unset -v line1 line2 line3
for var in line1 line2 line3; do
  IFS= read -r "$var" || break
done < input.txt
```

Or to automatically define the names of the variables as `line<++n>`:

```
n=1; while IFS= read -r "line$n"; do
  n=$((n + 1))
done < input.txt
```

Note that `bash` supports array variables and a `readarray` builtin to read lines into an array:

```
readarray -t line < input.txt
```

Note however that contrary to most other shells, `bash` array indices start at 0 not 1 (inherited from `ksh`), so the first line will be in `${line[0]}`, not `${line[1]}` (though [as @Costas has shown](/a/339997), you can make `readarray` (aka `mapfile`) start writing the values at indice 1 (`bash` arrays also contrary to most other shells' being *sparse* arrays) with `-O 1`).

See also: [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Answer (score 14):

I'd offer to use array for such task(s)

```
mapfile -t -O 1 var <input.txt
```

so you'll have each line in `${var[1]}`, `${var[2]}` and so on

Comment: This one-liner works very well. Solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not strictly what you asked for, but it might work for your needs. You
can serialize the data with Awk. Note that this will break if your $1 is not a
valid variable name:

```
awk '
function quote(str,   d, m, x, y, z) {
  d = "\47"; m = split(str, x, d)
  for (y in x) z = z d x[y] (y < m ? d "\\" d : d)
  return z
}
{
  print $1 "=" quote($0)
}
' input.txt > /tmp/input.sh
. /tmp/input.sh
```

Result:

```
$ echo "$line1"
line1 foo foobar bar
```

Comment: This is seriously strange code! It appears that you're using awk to turn the whole input file into a bash script which you then source. I have a vague idea of what quote() is doing. More descriptive variable names would help. Could you explain things a bit more?