# Escape unusual characters on filenames with `find . -printf "%p \n"`

Tags: find, special-characters

The file paths coming from this `find` command

```
find . -printf "%p \n"
```

do not escape unusual (whitespace, backslash, double quote...) characters.

The `-ls` option does print the escaped paths, but it just prepends the output of `ls -dils` to the output of `printf`.

I need a highly efficient command, so running an extra `ls` does not help, and neither does printing out all the extra characters.

Is there any other (elegant) way to ouput escaped paths with `find`?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?  A very common approach is to run the command in `find -exec` instead, which obviates the need to escape any shell metacharacters.

Comment: What do you want to do with the (quoted) output of that find? Read it with the shell, save to a file, run some commands on the file names?

Comment: If the next step of the pipeline can read `nul`-terminated paths, then just use `-print0`.

Comment: @tripleee and @ilkkachu: I am trying to find an alternative to `getfacl` to backup ACLs, which executes terribly slow on large filesystems. With `find` I could easily print filenames and permissions in octal format into a file and easily restore them with `chmod $1 $2`. But this won't work if $2 has special characters.

Comment: @JulenLarrucea, ACL:s are still quite different from just the permission bits, I don't think you can get them with `find`.

Comment: This is becoming quite an annoyance for my dynamic m3u files in VLC!

Comment: BLUF: `find` can just be slow.I'll just comment that another use case for outputting escaped filenames is the situation where the `find` command takes a long time to run, and you don't know up front what you want to do with those files.  I was just in that situation; I had to look at the content of the files, eliminate some irrelevant ones, and then interpret the JSON in the remaining files to find a path to a different file.  There were a number of false steps in the latter, and having a plain text file containing the output avoided the need to run `find` each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you'd want to use `find -exec` to run a command for all file names, or `find -print0` to pipe the names to some command that can read entries separated by nul bytes (like `xargs -0`).

If you really want to have quoted strings, Bash has a couple of options to do that:

```
$ find -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${@@Q}"' sh {} +
'./single'\''quote'
'./space 1'
$'./new\nline'
'./double"quote'

$ find -exec bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$@"' sh {} +
./single\'quote
./space\ 1
$'./new\nline'
./double\"quote
```

This does require an extra invocation of the shell, but handles multiple file names with one exec.

---

Regarding saving the permission bits (not ACL's though), you could do something like this (in GNU find):

```
find -printf "%#m:%p\0" > files-and-modes
```

That would output entries with the permissions, a colon, the filename, and a nul byte, like: `0644:name with spaces\0`. It will *not* escape anything, but instead will print the file names as-is (unless the output goes to a terminal, in which case at least newlines will be mangled.)

You can read the result with a Perl script:

```
perl -0 -ne '($m, $f) = split/:/, $_, 2; chmod oct($m), $f; ' < files-and-modes
```

Or barely in Bash, see comments:

```
while IFS=: read -r -d '' mode file ; do
    # do something useful
    printf "<%s> <%s>\n" "$mode" "$file"
    chmod "$mode" "$file"
done < files-and-modes
```

As far as I tested, that works with newlines, quotes, spaces<strike>, and colons</strike>. Note that we need to use something other than whitespace as the separator, as setting `IFS=" "` would remove trailing spaces if any names contain them.

Comment: Thanks! but I am searching for something _super_ fast. The `-type` option uses _lstats_ which slows down the process too much. The `-exec` should be also slow. I want to quick backup the permissions of huge filesystems.

Comment: @JulenLarrucea, oh, the `-type f` was an accident, but you do need to use `stat()` to get the file permissions anyway.

Comment: The `IFS=: read -rd '' mode file` won't work for file paths that end in `:` (and contain no other `:`). Use `-printf '%#m/%p\0` and `IFS=/ read -rd/` instead.

Comment: @ilkkachu: That's what I was doing. But well... If it is such a big deal, I'll keep the special characters and process them just in case of restoring.
Or I'll probably just drop the whole idea, since the performance seems even worse than with the standard `getfacl`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, ... Apparently so, but what's the logic causing that? I though only whitespace in `IFS` was handled specially and trailing whitespace eaten?

Comment: Because IFS is the Internal Field _Delimiter_ in POSIX shells (not zsh nor pdksh), not separator. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/22565

Comment: IMO that still doesn't make much sense regarding that _multiple_ colons seem to work fine, in the middle or in the end. But, whatever, I already knew   the shell's string processing is weird...

Comment: That's the same reason as why `a=a::b:` is split (in `printf '<%s>\n' $a` for instance) into `a`, `<empty>`, `b` and not `a`, `<empty>`, `b`, `<empty>`.

Comment: First one doesn't work. In `bash`, I get `sh: ${@@Q}: bad substitution`. Changing `${@@Q}` to `$@` is accepted, but it doesn't escape special characters.

Comment: @Melab, it works in Bash 4.4, though not in 4.3 or before. ([described here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html))

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
print -r -- ./**/*(.D:q)
```

`.` being the equivalent of `-type f`, `D` being to include hidden files like `find` would, and `:q` for quoting (using `zsh`-style quoting, I can't tell if that's the kind of quoting you're expecting).

You can get different styles of quoting with:

```
$ print -r -- ./**/*(.D:q)
./$'\200' ./a\ b ./é ./\"foo\" ./It\'s\ bad ./$'\n'
$ files=(./**/*(.D))
$ print -r -- ${(q)files}
./$'\200' ./$'\n' ./a\ b ./é ./\"foo\" ./It\'s\ bad
$ print -r -- ${(qq)files}
'./�' './
' './a b' './é' './"foo"' './It'\''s bad'
$ print -r -- ${(qqq)files}
"./�" "./
" "./a b" "./é" "./\"foo\"" "./It's bad"
$ print -r -- ${(qqqq)files}
$'./\200' $'./\n' $'./a b' $'./é' $'./"foo"' $'./It\'s bad'
```

(`�` being a placeholder displayed by my terminal emulator for that non-printable \200 byte).

Here, if you want to be able to store the permissions in such a way that  can be restored, it's just a matter of:

```
find . -type f -printf '%m\0%p\0' > saved-permissions
```

To be restored (assuming GNU `xargs`) with:

```
xargs -r0n2 -a saved-permissions chmod
```

That would however run one `chmod` invocation per file, which would be terribly inneficient. You may want to use a shell where `chmod` is builtin like `zsh` again after `zmodload zsh/files`:

```
zmodload zsh/files
while IFS= read -rd '' mode && IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  chmod $mode $file
done < saved-permissions
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a far more simple solution:

```
find -exec echo \'{}\' \;
```

We may use this to pipe to any other program:

```
find -exec echo \'{}\' \; | xargs ls
```

Or we can simply use any command instead of echo and add any number of arguments:

```
find -exec mv \'{}\' somewhereelse \;
```

Don't forget to prepend `echo` for testing first.

**The last DOES NOT WORK** because mv does not remove the quotes before accessing the file, use pipe instead:

```
find -exec echo mv \'{}\' somewhereelse \;| bash
```

Comment: So what would you do if the file contains a single quote, as in `it's my file`?

Comment: just guessing: use " quotes instead. or escape the single '? No idea currently ;)

Answer (score 2):

To print nicely quoted and escaped filenames (correctly handling apostrophes and quotes together) try the following:

```
find . -exec printf "%q\n" {} \;
```

which will produce (for example)

```
.
./DSC07051_.jpg
./Photos
"./Photos/TestDSC9910'Apos .jpg"
'./Photos/TestDSC9913 Space.jpg'
./Photos/DSC07053+.jpG
./Photos/DSC07048.jpg
./Photos/Photos.zip
'./Photos/TestDSC9912(x)Braces.jpg'
'./Photos/TestDSC9911"Quote.jpg'
'./Photos/TestDSC9919'\''The" (Lot).jpg'
./Photos/TestDSC9901Jpeg.jpEg
./DSC07053.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not escaping EVERY character? It then works for anything (ls, rm, echo etc.):

`find -name *.txt | sed -E 's/(.)/\\\1/g' | xargs ls`

(you'll probably need to adapt it to the `-exec` form so it becomes more efficient)

Comment: Would probably still not work if the filename contained newlines. It would be better to use `-print0` and then read the names as a `nul`-delimited list, or execute the utility directly from `find` with `-exec`.