# Can’t echo variable value=* in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, wildcards

Content of myfile:

```
123  
**1    
**
```

Script that attempts to display each word:

```
for i in $(cat $myfile)  
do  
  echo "$i"  
done
```

the result is when `echo *`, it lists the files in my current directory which I dnno why. So I tried to process the `*` before echo it.

Content of another script:

```
for i in $(cat $myfile)  
do  
  if [[ $i == *\+ ]](regex pattern find 1 * or more.)  
  then  
       （？what should I do. I tried i="\*",i="*" etc.; it doesn't work)  
  fi  
  echo "$i"  
done
```

Comment: thanks for editing!! i am new in linux .you mean using script to processing text is a bad practice? i expect the shell can do more.
anyway do you have solution ?? i just want to know why.
if i echo * in a script solely.its okay but if i loop every word in text file and pass to variable and echo it.something wrong with the asterisk character!

Comment: The shell can do more, but other tools can do it better. It depends on what you want to do with the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name globbing happens on the `for`-line, with the expansion of `$(cat $myfile)`, not in the `echo`.

When looping over the contents of a file, use `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r words; do
    printf '%s\n' "$words"
done <"$myfile"
```

See also:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understandig-ifs-read-r-line)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

---

If you want to have each whitespace-separate word on its own line of output:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i }' "$myfile"
```

Comment: Actually, since the OP says they are trying to display *each word* in the file, changing ``IFS`` might not be the right thing to do.

Comment: @G-Man If you want to read more words with `read`, then you have to use more variables. It's better to use `awk` (as I've done) or possibly (but not really) `readarray`/`mapfile`.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is: Don’t use a shell loop to process text. 
But, if you want a quick fix,

```
set -o noglob
for i in $(cat $myfile)
do
    echo "$i"
done
set +o noglob
```

The `noglob` option prevents pathname expansion,
so you can say `echo *` and get a `*` rather than a list of files.

Answer (score -1):

You're really asking two questions, but both speak to how the shell treats the character `*`. That character has special meaning to the shell, and as you discovered, it acts as a particular form of regular expression known in the shell man pages as a *glob* for file names. That's why you got the list of file names in your current directory, It is supposed to that. Refer to the shell man page section on globbing for a detailed description of all the forms of that particular kind of regular expression syntax.

The second part of question seems to be asking how to avoid that from happening. There are two ways. Either *escape* the character by preceding it with a back slash `\`, or put it in single quotes, ie. `'*'`.

Comment: A filename globbing pattern is not a "special form of regular expression".