# What does "${line#*'Caused By'}" != "$line" mean in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

Can someone explain what this means in a shell script?

```
while read -r line
do 
  if [ "${line#*'Caused By'}" != "$line" ]; then
    echo "Yes"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`${line#*'Caused By'}` is a specific instance of the variable substitution `${parameter#word}` (as it's written in the `bash` manual, and also [in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for the `sh` shell).

In `${parameter#word}`, the pattern `word` will be removed from the beginning of the value of `$parameter`. It's called "Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern" because it will remove the *shortest* matching prefix string that matches the pattern in `word` (with `##` in place of `#` it removes the *longest* matching prefix string).

It this specific example, the string `Caused by` (and anything before it, thanks to the `*`) is, if it exists, removed from the value of `$line`.  The single quotes around the string are redundant.

By comparing the result of the substitution with the value of the variable itself, the test determines whether the value of `$line` contains the text `Caused by`, and prints `Yes` if it does.

This has the same effect as

```
if [[ "$line" == *'Caused by'* ]]; then
    echo 'Yes'
fi
```

in `bash`, `ksh93` or `zsh`, or

```
case "$line" in
    *'Caused by'*) echo 'Yes'
esac
```

in any `sh` shell.

---

The loop in the question reads "lines" from standard input.  See the question "[Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line)
" for a discussion about this.

Answer (score 6):

The left-hand side of the if-condition uses the [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) functionality of bash. The matched string will be removed if it includes the 'Caused By'. The line will no longer be identical to what it was before and therefore it will not trigger the if-clause.

Here is an example that you can run on the shell:

```
echo -e "Number 1 Caused by me.\nNumber 2 is normal.\n" |
  while read line; do
    echo "${line#*'Caused by'}"
  done
```

Result:

```
 me.
Number 2 is normal.
```

Answer (score 3):

Action (or execution in this case) always speaks louder, so let's look at what this script does when executed (excuse the liberty taken to make the output more verbose):

```
while read -r line
do 
  if [ "${line#*'Caused by'}" != "$line" ]; then
    echo "Line contains string Caused by"
  else
    echo "Line does not contain string Caused by"
  fi
done

Input: String with Caused by
Output: Line contains string Caused by
Input: Just a normal string
Output: Line does not contain string Caused by
```

The pattern matching used in this script `"${line#*'Caused by'}` is replacing all string (owing to the wildcard `*`) from the beginning to the end of ***Caused by*** in the inputted line and then it compares it with the original `$line` parameter to see whether they are equal or not. Simple stated, all it does is a check whether the line contains the string *Caused by*. Finally it prints *Line contains string Caused by* if the line does contain *Caused by*.

Now, a few words about the shell parameter expansion for the `${parameter#word}` format with some examples:

> If the pattern matches the beginning of the  value  of  parameter, then  the  result  of  the  expansion  is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the "#'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the "##'' case) deleted.

```
$ test=aabbcc
$ echo ${test#*bb}                                                                    
$ cc

$ test=aabbcc
$ echo ${test#a*b}                                                                    
$ bcc
```

An example of the longest matching pattern format:

```
$ test=aabbcc
$ echo ${test##a*b}                                                                     
$ cc
```

**Reference:** `man bash`: `${parameter#word}`

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification! Editing the answer to speak about ${parameter#word}

Comment: Seems correct but not much different from Kusalananda's answer.