# How can I add random string for each line?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to add random string for each line while running:

```
awk '{print "name" "'$ran'" "-"$0}' 'myfile'
```

Before that, the random string is generated:

```
ran="$(tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 6)"
```

The problem is that it will print the same random string for each line:

```
nameGQz3Ek-
nameGQz3Ek-
nameGQz3Ek-
```

What should I do in order to get different random string for each line?

Comment: Instead of some variation of `tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 6`, it would simpler and more computationally efficient to use `pwgen -s 6 1`, or better yet `pwgen -s 6 $(wc -l myfile)` will give you exactly all the random strings you need, in one shot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With **awk** **`system()`** function:

Sample `input.txt`:

```
a
b
c
```

---

```
awk '{ 
         printf "name";
         system("tr -dc \047[:alnum:]\047 </dev/urandom | head -c6");
         printf "-%s\n", $0
     }' input.txt
```

Sample output:

```
nameSDbQ7T-a
nameAliHY0-b
nameDUGP2S-c
```

> **`system(command)`**
>       Execute the operating system command `command` and then return to the awk program

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-system_0028_0029-function

Comment: Nice, but why I'm getting `tr: write error: Broken pipe`?

Comment: @user134969, it works fine. Make sure that you haven't made any errors at the command line

Answer (score 10):

Don't you think its bit obvious? You are just generating random string once and storing it in `ran` variable and using it for all the lines!

Using `getline` into a variable from a pipe

```
awk '{
     str_generator = "tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 6"
     str_generator | getline random_str
     close(str_generator)
     print "name " random_str " - " $0
}' file
```

When you use `command | getline var`, the output of command is sent through a pipe to `getline()` and into the variable `var`.

Also note when a pipe is opened for output, `awk` remembers the command associated with it, and subsequent writes to the command are appended to the previous writes. We need to make an explicit `close()` call of the command to prevent that.

If the nested single-quotes in the `str_generator` are causing a problem, replace with its octal equivalent(`\047`)

```
awk '{
     str_generator = "tr -dc \047[:alnum:]\047 </dev/urandom | head -c 6"
     str_generator | getline random_str
     close(str_generator)
     print "name " random_str " - " $0
}' file
```

Answer (score 8):

Running one instance of `tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | head -c 6` per line of input would be counter-productive, you'd be better of doing:

```
<input awk -v rng="LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | fold -w 6" '
  {rng | getline r; print "name"r"-"$0}'
```

Answer (score 5):

This variation on a couple of the other answers does the random string generation outside of `awk`:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom | fold -w 6 |
awk '{ getline r <"/dev/stdin"; printf("name%s-%s\n", r, $0) }' file
```

The `tr`+`fold` pipeline generates an endless stream of random six-character strings on the standard input of `awk`.  `awk` will ignore the standard input if a filename is provided, so these random strings are read by `getline` from `/dev/stdin` into the variable `r`.  `printf` is then used to prefix the lines from the file with the appropriate string.

Given the file

```
123
abc
@#$
```

this may produce

```
nameFI4L1S-123
name5S8Shr-abc
namebRUjzV-@#$
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using awk at all, just simple `bash`

```
while read line; do
    printf "name%s-%s\n" \
        "$(tr -dc '[:alnum:]' </dev/urandom|head -c6)" \
        "$line"
done <myfile
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you may corrupt the data read from the file. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line

Answer (score 0):

```
paste <(base64 -w6 /dev/urandom) input.txt | awk 'NF==2{print $1$2} NF!=2{exit}'
```

**Requirements** - the input.txt should contain only one column, in other words, it shouldn't have tabs or spaces, because they used as default separator by `awk` and `paste` (only tab character) commands. Otherwise, the command must be modified a little bit.

**Note:**
The **Base64** alphabet contains `+` and `/` characters: [Base64 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table), if you want only numbers and letters, you can use `base32` command - [Base32 alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#RFC_4648_Base32_alphabet).

**Input**

```
===my_line_a
===my_line_b
===my_line_c
===my_line_d
===my_line_e
```

`===` characters added for clarity.

**Output**

```
LYSdm8===my_line_a
5sSSNt===my_line_b
YVMdkA===my_line_c
3b/nsT===my_line_d
xt/AZO===my_line_e
```

Answer (score 0):

As Inian suggested, the problem with your code is that you're just setting the variable *once*, not for each line.

If you want, you can probably do this in pure awk without the need to hit an external command repeatedly. Running an external command, whether in `system` or through redirection, may be slow. (Guessing. I haven't done comparisons. If you do, I'd love to see your results.)

Here's something that prints a different random string at the end of each line, using awk's internal `rand()` function:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function rstring(ln,   out) {
        out=""
        while (ln>0) {
                out=sprintf("%s%c", out, int(rand()*94+33))
                ln--
        }
        return out
}

BEGIN {
        srand()
        len=8
}

{
        r=rstring(len)
        printf("%s%s\n", $0, r)
}
```