# Compact way to get tab-separated fields into variables

Tags: bash, csv, array

In Bash, I'm reading out fields from a line into an array. Let me stress that performance is an issue, so I can't afford anything that spawns subprocesses.

To make the code more readable, I want the fields into variables: `$width` is more readable than `${array[0]}`. I have to manually set each and every variable, like this, which is a lot of repetition:

```
while read line; do

  array=($line)
  width=${array[0]}
  height=${array[1]}
  size=${array[2]}
  date=${array[3]}
  time=${array[4]}

  # use $width, $height, etc. in script

done < file
```

Is there any compact way to do it, like the `list` directive in PHP?

```
list($width, $height, $size, $date, $time) = $array;
```

Comment: How is `line` being set?

Comment: Additionally, you're open to [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) with `array=($line)`, unless you also `set -f`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes:

```
while read -r width height size thedate thetime; do
    # use variables here
done <file
```

This will read from standard input and split the data on blanks (spaces or tabs).  The last variable will get any data that is "left over" (if there are more fields than variables read).  This is *instead of* reading into the variable `line`.

I've used variable names `thedate` and `thetime` instead of `date` and `time` that are names of utilities.

To split the line on *only tabs*, set `IFS` to a tab for `read`:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r width ...etc...
```

See also:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Performance is a factor for me. Does `read` spawn a subprocess, or is it about as fast as direct variable assignment?

Comment: @forthrin `read` does not spawn a subprocess (if it did, it would not be able to set the variables for the rest of the script). It is not slower than splitting the `$line` and assigning the variables separately.

Comment: @forthrin If the loop could be done as an `awk` script, that would probably be faster still.

Comment: Ah! Brilliant! I actually knew you could do `read -r`, but I just didn't think of doing that directly in the `while`!

Comment: @forthrin The `-r` is just to properly read backslashes. It's something I add as a reflex.

Comment: You're right. So simply by putting multiple variables, each line is split into those? I'll surely use this in the future.

Comment: @forthrin Correct. The input is split on the values in `$IFS`.

Comment: If you actually ever need the values in an array, `read -a` will do that, FWIW.

Comment: Since OP asked about TAB delimited data, be aware that empty columns make `read` assign data to the wrong variables. E.g.: `echo $'1\t\t3'|while IFS=$'\t' read -r a b c ; do echo "$a/$b/$c"; done`
One way around this with `read` is to use arrays, indeed. E.g.: `echo $'1\t\t3'|while read -r ; do readarray -d$'\t' -t array < <(printf %s "$REPLY"); echo "${array[0]}/${array[1]}/${array[2]}"; done`