# bash is stripping leading whitespace from variables

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash (ksh only up until now). I'm struggling with whitespace being striped from variables.  I've read a number posts on bash's treatment of leading whitespace but I'm not sure how to correct it in my example.

```
echo "No space"         > x.tmp
echo "     Some space" >> x.tmp
cat x.tmp
cat x.tmp | while read line
do
   echo "$line" >> y.tmp
done
cat y.tmp
```

Output:

```
No space
     Some space
No space
Some space
```

What do I need to do to preserve the whitespace?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line

Answer (score 8):

You need to do

```
while IFS= read -r line
```

Setting IFS to the empty string will preserve whitespace.
Using `-r` will preserve any backslash sequences in the text.

---

If performance is a concern, note that a `while read` loop is **very** slow in bash. If you want to slurp the input into lines, and memory consumption is not a problem, read the input into an array of lines:

```
mapfile -t lines < x.tmp
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    do_something_with "$line"
done
```

Comment: That did it. :-)   I never would have thought of that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Richard Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).