# for loop variable assignment with whitespaces

Tags: shell-script, for, variable-substitution

Im collecting the LPAR names and assigning to a variable on AIX , Then using multiple commands for processing.

LPAR Names on the system are : ABCD56777 TSM Mobile CD CPT 2

```
for lparname in `lssyscfg -r lpar -m $system -F name,lpar_env |cut -f 1 -d, | sort`;
```

But the above for loop variable doesn't pick up the complete LPAR value after the space. (Exact LPAR name is: ABCD56777 TSM Mobile CD CPT 2 )

It assigns the value of LPAR as ABCD56777 alone.

Could you advise me on how to assign variable with spaces. Unfortunately awk is not installed and only sed will work.

Comment: There is no assignment taking place in the code that you show.  Please [edit] your question and add exactly what you're doing along with the expected result.  It would also be good to know what the output of the `lssyscfg` command is as some of us don't have access to systems with that command.

Comment: command substitution should now use syntax `$()` instead of ` `command` `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your command substitution expands to a whitespace-delimited string and the loop will iterate over all *words* in that string.  A "word" is anything delimited by a space, tab or newline character.

Also note that in Bourne-like shells other than `zsh`, those words are further subject to filename generation (aka globbing), so wildcard characters (and `{` in some shells) would also be a problem in addition to space and tab.

```
lssyscfg -r lpar -m "$system" -F name,lpar_env | cut -d, -f 1 | sort |
while IFS= read -r lpar; do
     echo "$lpar"
done
```

This uses a `while` loop instead of a static `for` loop.  The `while` loop body is executed in a subshell (in `bash`), so the `lpar` variable will not exist after the end of the loop body.  That's not an issue if you only use the variable in the loop body though.

Related: [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line)

Another solution would be to set `IFS` to a newline before the loop (and reset it afterwards):

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'    # assumes bash
set -o noglob

for lpar in $( lssyscfg -r lpar -m "$system" -F name,lpar_env | cut -d, -f 1 | sort )
do
    echo "$lpar"
done

set +o noglob
IFS=$oldIFS
```

The default value of `$IFS` includes spaces, which is why your original loop iterates over the wrong things. I have also turned off filename globbing for the loop, as we otherwise might get unexpected results if the text returned from `lssyscfg` includes filename globbing patterns as discussed above.

This last variation is IMHO quite inelegant, and downright inappropriate for commands that produce more than a handful of lines of output.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thanks a lot for helping with the data. It print out the complete LPAR Names in that HMC console. 'ABCD56777 TSM Mobile CD CPT 2'

Comment: Many thanks everyone for helping with detailed solution

Answer (score -1):

I would try

```
for lpar in $(lssyscfg -r lpar -m $system -F name,lpar_env |awk -F, '{printf "\"%s\"",$1}' | sort) 
do
   echo "$lpar"
done
```

- use `$( )` as command substitution
- `{printf "\"%s\"",$1}` will quote argument

Comment: Inserting quotes in the output will not help. The split+glob operator doesn't do anything with quotes (though some implementations understand backslash as a wildcard operator that disables wildcard operators)