# Special content and line by line

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, line

commrads!
I have a file:

```
# cat file
'\\.\Aktiv Co. Rutoken S 00 00\USER1@R69-20180109'
'\\.\Aktiv Co. Rutoken S 00 01\USER2@R69-20180109'
```

and i need execute line by line:

```
for LINE in `cat file` 
do
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont $LINE
done
```

BUT! The file has special content like: ' \. . and etc. 
And when i start my script with "set -x" i see this:

```
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont ''\''\\.\Aktiv'
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont Co.
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont Rutoken
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont S
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont 00
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat /home/user/Aktiv`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont '00\USER1@R69-20180109'\'''
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont ''\''\\.\Aktiv'
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont Co.
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont Rutoken
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont S
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat file`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont 00
Error
+ for LINE in '`cat /home/user/Aktiv`'
+ /opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont '01\USER2@R69-20180109'\'''
```

IN THE IDEAL MUST BE:

```
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont '\\.\Aktiv Co. Rutoken S 00 00\USER1@R69-20180109'
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont '\\.\Aktiv Co. Rutoken S 00 01\USER2@R69-20180109'
```

I think it's all from special content (file). 
Any ideas?

Comment: `for` doesn't work line-by-line.

Comment: This is a FAQ: [How can I read a file line-by-line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you iterate over the output of `cat file`, you iterate over the *words*.

One solution:

```
PATH=/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64:$PATH

while IFS= read -r line; do
    certmgr -inst -cont "$line"
done <file
```

This will read the lines, one by one, and properly read the backslashes and the spaces between the words.  Notice the quoting of `$line`.  See "[Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)".

I originally included a version using `xargs`, but I noticed that this did not preserve the backslashes in the `file` data under some circumstances, and stripped away the single quotes.

Comment: # sh script.sh
+ PATH=/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/user/bin
+ IFS=
+ read -r words
+ certmgr -inst -cont ''\''\\.\Aktiv' Co. Rutoken S 00 '00\D.KLEMENTEV@R69-20180109'\'''
Error
+ IFS=
+ read -r words

Comment: @OlegKalinin It's difficult to read that, but it looks like you swapped two directories (`bin` and `amd64`) when you're setting the path.

Comment: use `set -x` and see this:
`''\''\\.\Aktiv' Co. Rutoken S 00 '00\D.KLEMENTEV@R69-20180109'\'''`
but it is not correct. This wil be correct:

Comment: @OlegKalinin Note that the tracing output of `set -x` may add and remove quotes from the actual command being executed. You should use `printf '%s\n' "$line"` to see what the actual string passed to the utility is.  If you double quote the expansion of `$line` on the command line (as I have done), the correct data will be passed to the utility.

Comment: With `"$line"` (double quote the expansion) analogous situation.
I did like this:
`Aktiv=$(cat file)
cat <<- EOF > final_file
/opt/cprocsp/bin/amd64/certmgr -inst -cont ${Aktiv}
EOF`
`bash final_file`
and I achieved the result. But in this situation i have 1 line in file.
In this situation
`# cat file
'\\.\Aktiv Co. Rutoken S 00 00\USER1@R69-20180109'
'\\.\Aktiv Co. Rutoken S 00 01\USER2@R69-20180109'`

Comment: @OlegKalinin I don't understand. Are you saying that the solution that I posted does not work? I really can't see how yours would work as `$Aktiv` is not even quoted in the here-document.