# How can i read the contents of multiple files?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I need to read the contents of multiple files, for now I can read the contents of just one file using the code below , this code further reads the contents present in "rules1.txt" using "strings" . I just need the same functionality but with multiple files to read in "apps.txt" .

```
for i in $(cat apps.txt);
do    
cd /local/apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem1/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/app/$i
echo $i >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules1.txt     done
for i in $(ls *.rul);do
echo $i  >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules1.txt      
strings $i  >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules.txt
```

Comment: `for i in $(ls *.rul);` you should never use `ls` result. use `for i in *.rul` this will work better and on all linux you will use your script on. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/53092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read the whole `apps.txt` file into a `for` loop.  In the general case, this could cause memory issues if the file is huge, and it would cause issues if any filename in `apps.txt` had spaces in them.  Don't loop over the output of `ls`. Also, quote variable expansions and use `printf` for outputting variable data.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346)

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh

appdir='/local/apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem1/EssbaseServer/essbaseserver1/app'
outdir='/data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays'

while IFS= read -r app; do
    printf '%s\n' "$app"
    for name in "$appdir/$app"/*.rul; do
        printf '%s\n' "${name##*/}"
        strings "$name"
    done
done <apps.txt >"$outdir/rules1.txt"
```

This would read `app` from the `apps.txt` file and would access all the `*.rul` files in the corresponding subdirectory under `$appdir`. The strings `$app` and `${name##*/}` (the basename of the current `*.rul` file) would be outputted in each iteration, along with the output of `strings`. The output would go to the `$outdir/rules1.txt` file.

Also related (to my solution):

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Answer (score 0):

From this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689063/1195001

```
while read i  ; do
    cd /local/apps/oracle/Middleware/user_projects/epmsystem1/EssbaseServe/essbaseserver1/app/$i
    echo $i >> /data/shellscripts/essbase/Operate/Overlays/rules1.txt
done < apps.txt
```

While is better suited than for for this task.

Comment: its unable to recognize the files within apps.txt with while

Comment: What you mean ? What is not working how it's not working ?