# Split and concatenate (create command line arguments from input file)

Tags: linux, shell-script, split

How to concatenate text from file of lines in format:

```
line1
line2
...
```

to get results like

```
-o line1:1 -o line2:1 ...
```

I found solution how to concatenate with a separator like this:

```
ds=`cat list.txt`
${ds//$'\n'/','}
```

But I can't figure out how to add prefix to each entry.

Comment: @mrc02_kr Be a bit careful with your edits. The result in this question was never delimited by newlines in the original. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do with the string that you create.  It looks like a set of command line options, so I'm going to assume that you want to use it as such together with some utility called `util`.

Here's a solution for `/bin/sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

listfile=$1

set --
while IFS= read -r line; do
    set -- "$@" -o "$line:1"
done <$listfile

util "$@"
```

This reads from the file given on the command line of the script and for each line read from that file, it sets the positional parameters to include `-o` and `LINE:1` where `LINE` is the line read from the file.

After reading all the lines, it calls `util` with the constructed list of command line arguments.  By using `"$@"` (with the double quotes) we ensure that each individual item in the constructed list of arguments is individually quoted.

With `bash` and using a `bash` array to hold the command line arguments that we create:

```
#!/bin/bash

listfile=$1

while IFS= read -r line; do
    args+=( -o "$line:1" )
done <$listfile

util "${args[@]}"
```

In both the examples above, the quoting is important.  Likewise is the fact that we create an *array of separate items* (each `-o` and each `LINE:1` are items in the list).  Another way to do it would have been to create a *single string* `-o LINE1:1 -o LINE2:1 etc.`, but this would have been interpreted as one single argument if used as `util "$string"` and would have undergone word splitting and filename globbing if used as `util $string` (this would have not worked if any line in the input file contained spaces, tabs or filename globbing characters).

Both scripts above would be used as

```
$ ./script.sh file
```

where `script.sh` is the executable script file and `file` is the input file name to read from.

Related:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understand-ifs-read-r-line)

Answer (score 2):

With a recent shell (e.g. `bash`), try

```
mapfile -t TMP <file
TMP=(${TMP[@]/%/:1})
echo ${TMP[@]/#/-o }
-o line1:1 -o line2:1 -o line3:1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/-o \1:1/' file.txt | xargs /path/to/command
```

The `sed` substitution reads as: replace the text in a given line with "-o the_original_text:1". Then the `xargs` command takes those modified lines of text and concatenates them as appropriate for command line arguments

Answer (score 0):

Input file:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Command:

```
perl -lpe '$\=" ";$_="-o $_:1"' input.txt
```

Alternative command:

```
awk '{ORS=":1 ";print"-o "$0}' input.txt
```

Output (the same for both commands):

```
-o line1:1 -o line2:1 -o line3:1
```