# Bash script : read text files using "AND" conditions with different lines

Tags: shell-script

I have created simple bash script with "AND" condition but not working :

```
#!/bin/bash

cat log3.txt | \
while read -r LINE
do
  if [[ $LINE =~ Host ]] && [[ $LINE =~ denied ]]  ; then echo $LINE;
fi
done
```

and here are content of log3.txt

```
Host: abcd.com
Access denied
```

If using OR condition it is working well, but I want to use the AND condition, so if the log contains both of the strings "Host" and "Access Denied", I will get output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** you are sure that the files to process are small (like your example), you can read the whole file in one go and test that:

```
 file=$(<log3.txt)
 [[ $file =~ Host ]] && [[ $file =~ denied ]] && echo "$file"
```

For a larger file, and assuming that `Host` comes before `denied` you may use a faster (for external files) sed:

```
 <log3.txt sed -n '/^Host/!d;p;:1;n;/\<denied\>/{p;q};b1'
```

Understand that this solution will strictly print the first line that starts with `Host` and the **following** (not in the same line) **first** line that contains `denied` as a word.

If you need to extract **several** pairs of `Host` - `denied`, change the `q` to a `b`, that will re-start the cycle:

```
 <log3.txt sed -n '/^Host/!d;p;:1;n;/\<denied\>/{p;b};b1'
```

A similar solution with awk that will print the last `Host` line that is just before a `denied` line (in pairs):

```
 awk  '  p==1 && /\<denied\>/     {d=$0;p=0}
                /^Host*/         {h=$0;p=1}
         { if(p==0&&h!=""&&d!="") {print h,RS,d;p=2} }
      '  <log3.txt
```

And the same logic (except that it will match `denied` anywhere on the line (not as a word)) in the shell:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 p=0
 while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [ "$p" = 1 ]; then
        case $line in
           *denied*)        deniedline=$line; p=0   ;;
        esac
    fi

 case $line in
    Host*)               hostline=$line; p=1   ;;
 esac

 if [ "$p" = 0 ] && [ "$hostline" ] && [ "$deniedline" ]; then
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$hostline" "$deniedline"
    p=2
 fi

 done <log3.txt
```

Comment: 2nd solution doesn't quite work, it prints whatever comes before the first "Host" line and hangs on this input: `Host: ok.com/Access OK/Host: denied.com/Access denied`.

Comment: Yes, the first version assumed `denied` followed `Host` (as it is written on the answer). I made it a lot more robust now. Hard for me to think of a way to break it (until someone figure out how, of course :-) ).

Comment: yes 2nd solution it is OR condition

Comment: and the end solution it is work for me, and it is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In any single iteration of your `while` loop, the value `$LINE` can't be both `Host` *and* `denied`.  It's impossible given the data in the file.  This is why you get no output.

If you want to see all lines in the file that matches the two words `Host` *or* `denied`, use `grep` instead:

```
grep -wF -e 'Host' -e 'Access denied' <log3.txt
```

The options used here will ensure that we are doing string comparisons rather than regular expression matches (`-F`) and that we are matching complete words and not substrings (`-w`).  The two query strings are given with `-e` and we'll get any line containing *any* of these.

If you want to make a slightly more advanced query, which only shows the lines that contains the two words if they both appear in the file, then you could do it with an `awk` program instead:

```
awk '/Host/ { hostline=$0 } /Access denied/ { deniedline=$0 }
     END { if ((hostline != "") && (deniedline != ""))
               print hostline; print deniedline; }' <log3.txt
```

Here, if we find a line matching the string `Host`, we save it, and likewise for the string `Access denied`.  At the end, if both strings contain anything, we print them.

In more or less equivalent shell code:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        *Host*)
           hostline=$line   ;;
        *"Access denied"*)
           deniedline=$line ;;
    esac
done <log3.txt

if [ -n "$hostline" ] && [ -n "$deniedline" ]; then
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$hostline" "$deniedline"
fi
```

Here I use a `case ... esac` statement to do the matching on the read data.  The patterns used are filename globbing patterns, not regular expressions.

Related:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: `awk` code doesn't seem to work, try with `Host: denied1.com/Access denied/Host: ok.com/Access OK/Host: random.com`. The question is hard to answer since we don't know what the rest of the file looks like.

Comment: @xenoid I've made it slightly more robust, but you are correct that the intended behaviour is unclear.

Comment: Notes worth adding: The grep code will print **any** line with **either** `Host` or `Access denied`, **not** as **pairs**. The awk solution will only print the **last** instance of the pair.  The shell solution will match `Host` at any position on the line **and** will only print the last `Host` and the last `Access denied` found.

Comment: @Kusalananda grep -wF -e 'Host' -e 'Access denied' <log3.txt it is OR condtions, so it works for me when using use case ... esac

Comment: @WidiAnto Yes, I thought I made that  clear in my answer. I was showing a more efficient way of doing what you already had done. Then I showed how to implement the "and" condition.

Answer (score 0):

See @Kusalananda answer for why your solution doesn't work.

My solution using `grep -z`:

```
grep -zEo -e 'Host: (\w|\.)+\s+Access denied\s' log.txt
```

In slo-mo:

- `-E`: use extended regexp
- `-o`: print matches only
- `-z`: use `\0` as line delimiters. Since there are none, the search is done on the whole file, where `\n` is just a plain character.
- `- e'Host: (\w|\.)+\s+Access denied\s'`: look for:

  - "`Host:`"
  - A sequence of  letter, digits, or dots
  - A space-class character (which is going to  be `\n`)
  - "`Access denied`"
  - A space-class character (which is going to be `\n`). This one is need to get a linefeed on output

Running on:

```
Host: denied1.com
Access denied
Host: ok.com
Access OK
Host: random.com

Host: denied2.com
Access denied

More stuff
```

Yields:

```
Host: denied1.com
Access denied
Host: denied2.com
Access denied
```

Comment: this is not work for me, there'is no results after running the command

Comment: What is the input? Works for me with your two-lines  data if the last line ends with a linefeed (like all Linux logs do). If you want to the command to work even it if it is missing, just add a `?` at the end of the regexp:  `'Host: (\w|\.)+\sAccess denied\s?'`