# read issues with ls -i

Tags: bash, ls, read

If I write:

```
ls -i '/home/user/Desktop/file' | awk '{print $1}'
```

I get the inode number of the specified file.

I want to make a script that gives me back the inode number of a certain file.

If I do:

```
read file
'/home/user/Desktop/file2'
```

and then:

```
ls -i "$file" | awk '{print $1}'
```

It returns that `ls cannot find '/home/user/Desktop/file2'`.

why? thanks

Comment: Based on your post I'm not sure why you're using "read file". Are you trying to grab a filename from file2? Or do you mean:

    $FILE="/home/user/Desktop/file2"
    ls -i $FILE | awk '{ print $1 }'

Comment: after the read command I drag the file from desktop to terminal and it prints on shell the file path. terminal returns: ls: cannot access "'/home/user/Desktop/file2'": No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah, after reading muru's post below I understand what you're doing now. Totally not what I was imagining.

Answer (score 1):

In `ls -i '/home/user/Desktop/file'`, the shell removes the quotes around `/home/user/Desktop/file` before passing it to `ls`. `ls` gets `/home/user/Desktop/file` as the argument.

When you input `'/home/user/Desktop/file2'` to `read file`, those quotes are retained in the variable. Then, in `ls "$file"`, bash expands the variable, and removes the quotes which are not a result of variable expansion (so the `"..."` which were originally present in the command, but not the `'...'` from the variable's contents). `ls` gets `'/home/user/Desktop/file2'` as the argument, and of course, there's no such file.

You don't need to additionally have quotes inside a variable. If you want to enter a filename (including spaces and backslashes, etc.) more safely using `read`, use [this instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/70524):

```
IFS= read -r file
```

And as the input:

```
/home/user/Desktop/file2
```

Comment: when I drag a file into terminal by default it prints quotes at the beginning and at the end of the path dragged in. I tried to remove them with sed or tr command but it didn't work. How can I remove quotes when I drag files in terminal? [if I manually write the full path without quotes the script works]

Comment: You can try something like `file="$(eval "printf %s $file")"` or `file="$(sh -c "printf %s $file")"` - I think whatever does the quoting does it relatively safely for use in a shell command line, so if we use it as a part of a command for a new shell, or using `eval`, the quotes can be parsed out.

Comment: thanks. file="$(eval "printf %s $file")" works.

Comment: Hmm, `eval file="$file"` might be simpler.