# Find all empty directories AND directories with a single (specific) file

Tags: shell-script, find

I'm trying to write a shell script that deletes all empty directories
as well as any directory that contains only the `.DS_Store` file that Mac generates. 
I can do the former pretty easily with

```
find -depth -type d -empty
```

but I can't figure how to find directories that contain **only** `.DS_Store`.

Is there an easy way of doing this without writing my own recursive search function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### POSIX sh + find

Here's a solution that relies only on POSIX find and POSIX sh. List all directories, then filter those that only contain an entry called `.DS_Store`.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    cd "$0" &&
    for x in * .[!.]* ..?*; do
      if [ "$x" = ".DS_Store" ]; then continue; fi;
      if [ -e "$x" ] || [ -L "$x" ]; then exit 1; fi;
    done' {} \; -print
```

- I use `find` to enumerate all directories recursively.
- On each directory, I call `sh` to run some shell code.
- The `for` loop enumerates all the files in the directory.
- The body of the loop skips `.DS_Store`.
- Each of the three patterns is left unchanged if it doesn't match any file. `[ -e "$x" ] || [ -L "$x" ]` captures any file including broken symbolic links; the only way they don't match is if a pattern was left unchanged.
- Therefore the shell snippet runs `exit 1` if there is a file other than `.DS_Store`, and returns 0 for success otherwise.
- Change `-print` to `-exec …` if you want to do something other than printing the names.

#### Zsh

Here's a solution in zsh. Change `echo` to whatever command you want to run.

```
setopt extended_glob
echo **/*(/DNe\''a=($REPLY/^.DS_Store(DNY1)); ((!#a))'\')
```

- `**/*` enumerates all files recursively.
- With the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `/`, `**/*(/)` enumerates all directories recursively.
- The glob qualifier `N` ensures that you get an empty list if there are no matches (by default zsh signals an error).
- The glob qualifier `D` causes dot files to be included.
- The glob qualifier `e\''CODE'\'` runs `CODE`  on each matching file name and limits the matches to those for which `CODE` succeeds. `CODE` can use the variable `$REPLY` to refer to the file name.
- `^.DS_Store` matches files that are not called `.DS_Store`.
- Thus the *CODE* limits the matches to those for which the number of files other than `.DS_Store` is zero.
- The glob qualifier `Y1` limits the matches to one (it's only an efficiency improvement).

#### Python

Here's a solution in Python (it works in both 2 and 3). The structure is rather clearer despite this being compressed into a one-liner.

```
python -c 'import os; print("\n".join([path for path, dirs, files in os.walk(".") if dirs == [] and files in ([], [".DS_Store"])]))'
```

- `os.walk` returns a list of directories recursively under its argument. For each directory, it produces a triple containing `path` (the path to the directory), `dirs` (the list of subdirectories) and `files` (the list of files in the directory that aren't themselves directories).
- `[… for … in os.walk(…) if …]` filters the result of `os.walk`.
- The `if` clause keeps an element only if it has no subdirectories and no files other than `.DS_Store`.
- The script prints the accepted elements, joined with a newline in between and with a final newline.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:
first, delete all such files:

```
find <path> -type f -name "*.DS_Store" -delete
```

then delete empty directories.

**Update based on comment:**
In order to delete only directories that have only such files, you will need something like (caution: not tested at all, I will not be surprised if it needs to be a bit more involved):

```
find <path> -type d | while read dir; do
    if ! ls --ignore=*.DS_Store $dir; then
        rm -rf $dir
    fi
done
```

Explanation of complicated part:

```
ls --ignore=*.DS_Store $dir
```

should print files in $dir that do not end in .DS_Store.  If there are none, the expression is False and the if-block is executed.

Comment: I though of this but I don't want to delete all .DS_Store files, only the ones in directories that are otherwise empty.

Comment: Sorry to spoil the fun, but the standard `ls` on macOS doesn't know about `--ignore`...

Comment: in that case, --ignore can be emulated with suitable 'grep -v'

Comment: (1a) Quoting Stéphane Chazelas’s comment elsewhere on this page: “See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) (1b) If you’re going to use this approach, you need a lot more quotes. (2) Why are you checking for `*.DS_Store`? Yes, I see that you say you’re looking for files whose names end in `.DS_Store`; but why? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) Thank you for admitting that you didn’t test this, because I believe that it cannot possibly work, because `ls` doesn’t exit with an error just because it didn’t list any files.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac:

```
find . -type d | while read dir; do
    
    # Found empty dir if it only has:
    #   ., .. 
    #   ., .., .DS_Store
    
    if [ "$(ls -am "$dir" | sed -E 's/^., ..$|^., .., .DS_Store$//')" == "" ]; then
        echo rm -R "\"$dir\""
    fi
done
```

Comment: See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: (1) I believe that [Gilles’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489569/80216) will work on Mac; you didn’t really need to add another one.  (2) Fun fact:  your answer will report a directory that contains (only) a file called `zDS_Store`.  (3) You should explain how to switch your answer from debug mode to operational mode, since you have thrown a monkey wrench into it.

Answer (score 0):

Another POSIX variant with a bit more safeguards:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    contents=$(ls -AFq "$dir") &&
      case $contents in
        ("" | .[dD][sS]_[sS][tT][oO][rR][eE]) printf "%s\n" "$dir"
      esac
  done' sh {} +
```

Here:

- we bail out if `ls` can't list the directory contents (or can't find out the type of the files within).
- by using `ls -F`, we make sure we don't list a directory that contains a `.DS_Store` that is not a *regular* file (as `-F` adds suffixes for other types of files).
- With `-q`, we avoid false positives with files names `$'.DS_Store\n\n'` for instance.
- We match case insensitively as I believe filenames are case insensitive in macos.

A `zsh` equivalent could be:

```
empty() {
  set -o localoptions -o extendedglob
  ERRNO=0
  () ((!ERRNO && !$#)) $REPLY/(#i){^.ds_store(NDY1),.ds_store(N^.)}
}
print -rC1 -- **/*(ND/+empty)
```

Now, if the point is to remove those directories, there's the case where `dirA` contains only `dirB` and `dirA/dirB` is empty or only contains a `.DS_Store` file. Then, we wouldn't be reporting `dirA` even though it would become empty after `dirA/dirB` is removed.

To address that, that's where you would use `-depth`, but you wouldn't be able to use `-exec ... {} +` as it's important the empty directories are deleted as soon as they're found, so we'd use `-exec ... {} ';'` instead:

```
find . -depth -type d -exec sh -c '
  contents=$(ls -AFq "$1") &&
    case $contents in
      ("" | .[dD][sS]_[sS][tT][oO][rR][eE]) exec rm -rf "$1"
    esac' sh {} ';'
```