# How to match string in file

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm trying to reproduce this code in Python to Bash

```
import re
w = open("filetest.txt")
for item in re.findall(r'STRING:\s*(.+)"', w.read()):
  print item
```

In Bash, but I do not know if it's correct, this is returning nothing.

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ r'STRING:\s*(.+)"' ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done < filetest.txt
```

filetest `iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.3.2.1.11.1.1.1 = STRING: "785c7208dcf0"`

Output: `785c7208dcf0`

Comment: (1) It looks like all that code could be replaced by a simple `grep` command.  (2) If you provide some representative sample input and corresponding desired output, you will get better answers.

Comment: before make regex, I have a function which populate this text file with SNMP. Are you saying that you need this for loop ???

Comment: It looks to me like you do _not_ need a loop at all.  So that we can be sure that answers here really solve your problem, provide a brief but representative sample of that input text file and your corresponding desired output.  We don't need the SNMP code, just a representative part of `filetest.txt`.

Comment: Please provide the info John1024 requests so we can be sure. To be perfectly clear, it sounds like you are trying to recreate a basic function of GREP by reversing a piece of Python that does more or less what GREP fundamentally does by design already. Desired output and intention are important, if this isn't just a "I did not know GREP existed" question.

Comment: The output from your python code is different from the desired output that you show.  Which output do you really want?

Comment: No, I'm not posted the python output, `filetest` is the string to be analysed  and `ouput` is the resulted

Comment: The existing sample python code includes the leading double-quote in the output (i.e. using your sample input, I get `"785c7208dcf0` as the output), but the desired output does not. Which is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*STRING:[[:blank:]]*\(..*\)/\1/p' filetest.txt
```

You wouldn't do it in a shell loop as these are generally not ideal for parsing text (see "[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)").

Instead, the above single command uses `sed` to match the regular expression (here rewritten as a *basic regular expression* rather as a PCRE, a *Perl compatible regular expression*).  The editing command used with `sed` replaces the matching line with the captured text and outputs it.

Another way:

```
awk -F ':[[:blank:]]*' '/STRING/ { print $2 }' filetest.txt
```

This treats each line of the file as a record with fields delimited by `:` followed by any number of spaces or tabs. When the `STRING` pattern is found on a line, the second such field is printed.

Would you nonetheless want to do it with a `bash` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ 'STRING:'[[:blank:]]*(.+) ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done <filetest.txt
```

The `BASH_REMATCH` array will contain the various captured bits from the match.  The regular expression itself (which should be an *extended regular expression*) should not be quoted, apart form the bits that needs to be interpreted literally.  Note: This is where you went wrong; you quoted the regular expression and did not look in `BASH_REMATCH` for the captured data. You also tried to use the regular expression *exactly* the way you would write the expression in Python. `bash` is not Python.

Or,

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    match=$(expr "$line" : '.*STRING:[[:blank:]]*\(..*\)')
    if [ -n "$match" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$match"
    fi
done <filetest.txt
```

Given the input that you have in the question, the various variations above will all output

```
"785c7208dcf0"
```

See also:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)
- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)
- [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)