# Create file with content, where the content has new line

Tags: linux

In linux, **how to create a file** with content whose single line with \n (or any line separator) is translated into multi-line.

```
fileA.txt:
trans_fileA::abcd\ndfghc\n091873\nhhjj 
trans_fileB::a11d\n11hc\n73345
```

Code:

```
while read line; do
         file_name=`echo $line | awk -F'::' '{print $1}' `
         file_content=`echo $line | awk -F'::' '{print $2}' `
             echo $file_name
             echo $(eval echo ${file_content}) 
         echo $(eval echo ${file_content}) > fileA.txt
```

The trans_fileA should be:

```
abcd
dfghc
091873
hhjj
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Using the `bash` shell:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    name=${line%%::*}
    contents=${line#*::}

    echo -e "$contents" >"$name"
done <fileA.txt
```

This reads the input file line by line and extracts the output filename and the contents form the read line using [standard parameter substitutions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).  `${variable%%pattern}` removes the longest matching substring from the tail end of `$variable` that matches `pattern`, while `${variable#pattern}` removes the shortest matching substring from the start of `$variable` that matches `pattern`.

The value of `line` is read with `read -r` so that the backslashes are *preserved* in the data.  Without `-r`, `read` would not preserve these.  We also set `IFS` to an empty string before calling `read` so that no flanking whitespace is trimmed from the data.

The output is done using `echo -e`, which *interprets* the escape sequences in the data.  This means that it will replace the `\n` in the data with actual newlines.

After running this, you will have

```
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  71 Jun 17 16:28 fileA.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  24 Jun 17 16:31 trans_fileA
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  16 Jun 17 16:31 trans_fileB
```

```
$ cat trans_fileA
abcd
dfghc
091873
hhjj
```

```
$ cat trans_fileB
a11d
11hc
73345
```

Related:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was [sed](https://manpage.me/?sed)
Given your file, fileA.txt above:

```
abcd\ndfghc\n091873\nhhjj
```

and running `sed` against `newline.sed` which contains:

```
s/\\n/\
/g
```

thusly

`sed -f ./newline.sed <./fileA.txt >./trans_fileA`

will return these results in `trans_fileA`:

```
abcd
dfghc
091873
hhjj
```

This was the simplest way I could figure to accomplish your task.

HTH