# Shuffle words in a string

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a text file with newline delimited strings. My problem is to process each line as follows: shuffle the order of tokens by using space as a delimiter.

For example:

Input:
`A B C`

Output:
`C A B`

Running the command/script repeatedly should of course provide different order.

My current solution (for a single text line):

`$ cat <file> | tr " " "\n" | shuf | tr "\n" " "`

Is there a nice (a better) command line combo to process a text file with multiple lines?

Comment: don't abuse `cat`, `tr " " "\n" < <file> | shuf | tr "\n" " "` is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIXly, you could do it with `awk` relatively efficiently (certainly more efficiently than running at least one GNU `shuf` utility for each line of the input) as:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {srand()}
  {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      r = int(rand() * NF) + 1
      x = $r; $r = $i; $i = x
    }
    print
  }' < your-file
```

(note that in most `awk` implementations, running that same command twice in the same second is likely to give you the same result as the default random seed as used with `srand()` is generally based on the current epoch time in seconds).

Answer (score 4):

Your original command can be simplified to

`shuf -e A B C | tr "\n" " " && echo ""`

or

`shuffled=( $(shuf -e A B C) ) ; echo ${shuffled[*]}`

Which I think is a little less hacky and is also faster from my rudimentary tests.

If you have a file at `~/test` which contains

```
A B C
D E F
```

You can shuffle and echo each line with the following command

`while IFS= read -r line; do shuffled=( $(shuf -e $line) ) ; echo ${shuffled[*]} ; done < ~/test`

or in script form:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
    do shuffled=( $(shuf -e $line) )
    echo ${shuffled[*]}
done < ~/test
```

Where you might want to replace `~/test` with `$1` to pass arguments to the script.

result:

```
B C A
G E F
```

How this works:

`shuf -e` splits on spaces as well as newlines.. but only because it will treat A B C as three arguments.

so
`shuf -e A B C`
will shuffle A B and C
but `shuf -e "A B C"`
will not shuffle A B and C

We can use this to read each line into an array and then print it out again with `echo`.

`while IFS= read -r line;`

Reads in each line into `$line` when it is passed with `<` to this loop.

`do shuffled=( $(shuf -e $line) )`

Makes an array out of each line in the `$shuffled` variable, by literally expanding `shuf -e $line` to `shuf -e A B C`.

`echo ${shuffled[*]}`

echos our array, by default printing each element with spaces in between

`< ~/test`

feeds lines from `~/test` into our loop.

Comment: `while read line` will do backslash and IFS processing. Better to do `while IFS= read -r line`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/56167

Comment: Nice.. I wasn't aware of that, edited.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
$ cat file
A B C
D E F
G H I J
```

then using `shuffle` from perl's List::Util module:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -alpe '$_ = join " ", shuffle @F' file
C B A
E D F
I J G H
```

With bash `read -a` and `shuf` (but very inefficient as it runs 3 utilities per line, 2 of which not builtin):

```
$ while read -ra arr; do shuf -e -- "${arr[@]}" | paste -sd ' ' -; done < file
A C B
F E D
J I G H
```

Comment: Or we could shuffle the indices: `perl -MList::Util=shuffle -alpe '$_ = "@F[shuffle 0..$#F]"' file`

Answer (score 1):

To pass the parameters as one line:

`shuf -e one two three four` is what you need.

`shuf -e $(cat <file>) | tr "\n" " "` for a file with one line, as in your example.

For multiple lines:

`while read line; do shuf -e $line | tr "\n" " " && echo \n; done < <file>`

Comment: This will print each element out on a newline though..

Comment: @Zhenhir: edited.

Comment: That’s funny;  just a moment ago I read a comment that said “don’t abuse ```cat```”.

Comment: @G-Man: You are so right [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) creeps its ugly head everywhere. Here, however, it's needed, since shuf won't take a `shuf -e < file` as input.

Comment: Don't use `while read line`, use `while IFS= read -r line`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/56167

Comment: Ah, I misread your answer;  I thought you said ```cat <file> | tr "\n" " "```.

Answer (score 1):

While [like @steeldriver, I would use a proper text processing tool like `perl` to do the job](/a/539286), I'll mention a hacky way with the `zsh` shell:

```
while read -rA words; do
  print -r -- /(e['reply=($words)']noe['REPLY=$RANDOM'])
done < your-file
```

It's a bit of a hack. We end up using filename generation so as to be able to use the `o` glob qualifier which lets us implement arbitrary sorting orders.

Here, we're globbing `/` (which we know always exists), use a the `e` glob qualifier to replace it with the content of our array, and then do a `n`umerical `o`rdering based on the `REPLY=$RANDOM` `e`xpression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using the "much maligned" c-shell:

```
% foreach line ( "`cat input.txt`" )
     set tokens = ( $line:x )
     foreach ran_idx ( `seq $#tokens | shuf` )
         printf '%s\n' ${tokens[$ran_idx]:q}
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler one. Put your string into an array and use `shuf` to shuffle

```
SA=($"A B C")
shuf -e ${SA[@]}
```