# How to cut date and time in Unix Scripting

Tags: linux, text-processing, ksh

I'd like to ask how to use cut or other similar command to get date and time...
So basically, `$line` was retrieved from a `for loop`:

```
for line in $(cat $file);
do
   getdatetime=$(echo $line | cut -f4 -d,)
done
```

where the sample value for `$line` is:

```
883427446627317909,1114259,1573178423,2019-11-08 02:00:23,RD,4.7,0,351442429
```

The file `$file` contain multiple lines similar to the sample `$line`.

The expected value for `getdatetime` is:

```
2019-11-08 02:00:23
```

But i'm getting the date only:

```
2019-11-08
```

Is there any one-liner `cut` command to extract the date and time? I need to preserve the structure of the for loop. Thank you.

Comment: quote your command-substitution `getdatetime="$(echo" $line" | cut -f4 -d,)"`; Possible duplicate of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: hi @αғsнιη, i have done what you suggested but still, only the date is shown.

Comment: `line='883427446627317909,1114259,1573178423,2019-11-08 02:00:23,RD,4.7,0,351442429' ; getdatetime="$(echo "$line" | cut -f4 -d,)"; echo "$getdatetime"`?

Comment: Could you show us how you assign the value to your variable `line`?

Comment: Is there more than one line in the input file?  Because this loop looks like it will only save the last one -- is that what you want?

Comment: hi @JigglyNaga, yup there are multiple lines inside `$file` and all of the lines have similar construction

Comment: Why do you need  to use a `for` loop. A `for` loop _always iterates over a static set of words_, which means you would have to let the shell read the _complete file_ into memory only to iterate over it. This is extremely inefficient and inelegant. If you need to use a shell loop at all, you should be using a `while` loop, which reads individual lines (separately in each iteration).

Comment: So there are multiple lines of input, but you only want to save the date from the last one?  It's possible that you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda @JigglyNaga i am using for loop because i need the first field and the fourth field per each `$line`. i can easily get the first field but for the fourth field, only the date is fetched

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over the unquoted command substitution `$(cat $file)`, you iterate over all *words* that `cat $file` results in.  A word will be anything delimited by a whitespace (space, tab or newline by default).  This means that for a line in `$file` that is

```
883427446627317909,1114259,1573178423,2019-11-08 02:00:23,RD,4.7,0,351442429
```

you will have the two words `883427446627317909,1114259,1573178423,2019-11-08` and  `02:00:23,RD,4.7,0,351442429` (i.e. the loop would iterate twice for this single line).  This means that you'd get `2019-11-08` in the first iteration and `0` in the second from this line.

The solution is *not* to quote the command substitution as doing so would cause the loop to iterate *once* over the full contents of the file which is read into `$line`.  The solution is *not* to set `IFS` to a newline, as that is *inelegant* (it would necessitate one call to `cut` in each iteration).

Instead,  parse out the data that you want in a single call to `cut` and read that:

```bash
while IFS= read -r datetime; do
    # use "$datetime" here
done < <( cut -d, -f4 "$file" )
```

This uses a process substitution to create an input stream for the `while` loop to read from.  The data in this stream will consist of the 4th comma-delimited field in the file named by `$file`.

Alternatively, with the `while` loop in a subshell:

```bash
cut -d, -f4 "$file" |
while IFS= read -r datetime; do
    # use "$datetime" here
done
```

With `awk`, the processing would be cleaner (unless you *need* to use the date/time value as a shell variable for whatever reason):

```
awk -F , '{ datetime = $4; ... more code here using the datetime variable }' "$file"
```

Related reading:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)
- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Comment: hi @Kusalananda, is it possible to get the first field and fourth field at the same time for each `$line` and store them on different variables? like: `getid=883427446627317909` and `getdatetime=2019-11-08 02:00:23`

Comment: @dcdum2018 This was not part of the question. The first part of [bxm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551152/116858) would be easily modifiable to do this, just change the loop to `while IFS=, read getid _ _ getdatetime _`.

Answer (score 2):

We can actually do without `cut` if we want to:

```
while IFS=, read _ _ _ stamp _ ; do
  echo "do something with $stamp here"
done < "$file"
```

Breaking it down a bit:

`IFS=,` temporarily set the record separator to be `,`

`read _ _ _ stamp _` store fields 1-3 and 5 onwards in a throwaway variable, while capturing field 4 (your date/time) as `stamp`

`< "$file"` read in the source file (this is caught by our `read` command).

Another way to skin this cat, by populating an array with each line (this works in bash for sure, other shells may not support this or implement it in a different manner):

```
while IFS=, read -a line ; do echo "${line[3]}" ; done < "$file"
```

Comment: hi @bxm,  this line of code `while IFS=, read -a line ; do echo "${line[3]}" ; done < "$file"` is not working in `#!/bin/ksh`. i think the `-a` part is not working

Comment: Must be a bash-ism, you should be fine with the other version (or maybe there’s an option you can pass on ksh which does something similar?)

Comment: @dcdum2018 The `ksh93` shell has a `read` that implements reading into an array with `read -A`.  See the manual.