# Bash - print reversed file list using glob

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards, shellcheck

Is there a way to reverse a file list via glob?

So I would get the same result as with:

```
ls -r *
```

I'm using this in a shell-script and `shellcheck` keeps complaining:

> ^--------^ SC2045: Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.

Answer (score 7):

### zsh

With the `zsh` shell, the sorting order of globs can be customised with the `oC` (order), `OC` (same as `^oC` for reverse) and `n` (for numeric) glob qualifiers,

Quoting `info zsh qualifier`:

> `oC`
>
> specifies how the names of the files should be sorted.  If C is `n`
>        they are sorted by name; if it is `L` they are sorted depending on
>        the size (length) of the files; if `l` they are sorted by the number
>        of links; if `a`, `m`, or `c` they are sorted by the time of the last
>        access, modification, or inode change respectively; if `d`, files in
>        subdirectories appear before those in the current directory at each
>        level of the search -- this is best combined with other criteria,
>        for example '`odon`' to sort on names for files within the same
>        directory; if `N`, no sorting is performed.  Note that `a`, `m`, and `c`
>        compare the age against the current time, hence the first name in
>        the list is the youngest file.  Also note that the modifiers `^` and
>        `-` are used, so '`*(^-oL)`' gives a list of all files sorted by file
>        size in descending order, following any symbolic links.  Unless `oN`
>        is used, multiple order specifiers may occur to resolve ties.
>
> The default sorting is `n` (by name) unless the `Y` glob qualifier is
>        used, in which case it is `N` (unsorted).
>
> `oe` and `o+` are special cases; they are each followed by shell code,
>        delimited as for the `e` glob qualifier and the `+` glob qualifier
>        respectively (see above).  The code is executed for each matched
>        file with the parameter `REPLY` set to the name of the file on entry
>        and `globsort` appended to `zsh_eval_context`.  The code should modify
>        the parameter `REPLY` in some fashion.  On return, the value of the
>        parameter is used instead of the file name as the string on which
>        to sort.  Unlike other sort operators, `oe` and `o+` may be repeated,
>        but note that the maximum number of sort operators of any kind that
>        may appear in any glob expression is 12.

So here, to get the file list in reverse alphabetical order:

```
list=(*(NOn))
```

or

```
list=(*(N^on))
```

(here also using the `N` (for `nullglob`) qualifier so that if there's no matching file, the list becomes empty).

For the list sorted by modification time in reverse (like `ls -rt`):

```
list=(*(NOm))
```

With zsh, you can also sort the elements of an array with the `o` and `O` parameter expansion flags.

```
list=(*(N))
list_reversed=(${(Oa)list})
```

That is, `$list` sorted in reverse (because of the capital `O`) on `a`rray members.

### bash

With recent versions of the `bash` shell and with GNU `sort`, you can get a list of file names sorted in reverse with:

```
readarray -td '' list < <(
   shopt -s nullglob
   set -- *
   (($# == 0)) || printf '%s\0' "$@" | sort -rz)
```

`readarray -td '' array` reads a list of NUL-delimited records into an array.

With the GNU implementation of `ls`, another approach is to do:

```
eval "list=($(ls --quoting-style=shell-always -r))"
```

where `ls --quoting-style=shell-always` uses single quotes to quote file names (and `\'` outside of single quotes to quote single quotes themselves).

That approach also works with `yash` (assuming all file names are valid text in the locale), `ksh93`, `zsh` and `mksh`, though for `ksh93`, make sure you declare the variable as an array beforehand (with `typeset -a list`) otherwise if `ls` gives no output, that would create `$list` as a compound variable instead of an array variable.

Beware ast-open's `ls` implementation also supports a `--quoting-style=shell-always` option, but it uses the `$'...'` form of quoting which is not safe to use in all locales.

### POSIXly

POSIXly, in `sh`, to reverse the `"$@"` array, you can do:

```
eval "set -- $(awk 'BEGIN {for (i = ARGV[1]; i; i--) printf " \"${"i"}\""}' "$#")"
```

The idea being to have awk output something like `set -- "${3}" "${2}" "${1}"` when `"$@"` has 3 elements for instance

So to get that list of files in reverse order:

```
set -- *
eval "set -- $(awk 'BEGIN {for (i = ARGV[1]; i; i--) printf " \"${"i"}\""}' "$#")"
echo file list:
printf ' - %s\n' "$@"
```

Beware POSIX `sh` doesn't have any equivalent of the `nullglob` option (a `zsh` invention), zsh's `(N)` glob qualifier or ksh93's `~(N)` glob operator. If there's no non-hidden file in the current directory, you'll end up with a list with one `*` element. A common way to work around it is to do:

```
set -- [*] *
case "$1$2" in
  ('[*]*') shift 2;;
  (*)      shift;;
esac
```

Where the `[*]` combined with `*` is a way to discriminate between a `*` that comes from *no match* (where `[*]` would also expand to `[*]`) and one that comes from a file called `*` literally (where `[*]` would expand to `*`).

---

In any case, if you're going to pass a list of file names to `ls` for it to sort it like in your `ls -r *` approach where the shell passes the expansion of `*` to it and you'll want to use the `-d` option and mark the end of options with `--`:

```
ls -rd -- *
```

But, that output will still not be post-processable reliably since the file names are delimited by newline characters and the newline character is as valid as any in a file's name.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this question is about reversing the list resulting from a filename globbing pattern, and not about reimplementing the exact output of `ls -r`.

Get the result of the glob match into e.g. the positional parameters:

```bash
set -- *
```

Then reverse that list:

```
names=()
for name do
    shift
    names[$#]=$name
done
```

This creates an array called `names` that contains the matches of the `*` globbing pattern reversed.

The reversing is done by iterating over the positional parameters (the result of the match) in order, and for each entry, inserting it in the position it would have in the reverse list. `$#` is the number of positional parameters (matches of our globbing pattern) and `shift` removes one from this list, decrementing `$#` by one in each iteration, so we're inserting elements from the start of the list of positional parameters into the end of the `names` array.

Once you have the `names` array, print it:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
```

... or do whatever else you need to do with it.

This will *not* be the same as `ls -r *` as the `ls` command would list the contents of any directory matched by the `*` glob.

When the pattern does not match anything, `bash` will leave the pattern unexpanded.  Use `shopt -s nullglob` to set the shell's `nullglob` option, which, when activated, will remove the pattern completely when it does not match any name.  To match hidden names, additionally set the shell's `dotglob` option.

Comment: You wouldn't want to do with the `bash` shell in a directory with more that a few dozen files as array manipulation in `bash` is excruciatingly slow. Here, in a directory with about 17k files, and with bash5, it's still not finished after 3 minutes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That is true. The list reversing loop recreates the list in each iteration, probably leading to all sorts of interesting memory fragmentation issues (or whatever it is that slows it down). I'll make an alternative loop instead, using indexing.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The new loop should be faster. I dropped the alternative using a named array instead of the list of positional parameters as the syntax would have been to wordy. Also, you can't "shift" a named array in `bash` without recreating it.

Comment: For the record, in that 17k files directory, that previous approach took 5 minutes in bash, 33 seconds in zsh, 1:08 minute in ksh93, 1:17 in yash, still not finished after 8 minutes in mksh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, there's some sort of suboptimal memory management happening there. In any case, the new code in the answer should only take a fraction of a second (or possibly a single digit number of seconds) to run.

Comment: That's much better now (2 seconds in bash) though still not as fast as my GNU or POSIX approaches (;-b)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which shell you're using, I've never yet run across a shell that globs in anything but ascending alphanumeric order. So this is something you'll need to do with `ls`, `sort`, or something of the sort.
See [the shellcheck wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2045) for why iterating over the output of `ls` is fragile, and what to do about it.
Basically, there are two main problems to watch out for: 1) when a directory is empty, `echo *` prints `*` by default. 2) If you have files with spaces in their names, that can confuse whatever's reading the input.
For (1), if you're using bash, you'll want to set the `nullglob` option.
For (2), you'll probably want to write something along the lines of

```
ls -1r | while read filename; do
    ...
done
```

(again, assuming that you're using `sh`, `bash`, or `zsh`.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm using `bash`, please check the title and `tag`:-)

Comment: [`read filename` is not how you read a line of input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/22565). Even if you fix it to `IFS= read -r filename`, that still won't work properly if there are file names with newline characters.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting iterating over the output of `ls` as a remedy for iterating over the output of `ls`.

Comment: `zsh` is one of those shells where the glob order is customisable. It's also the shell where the `nullglob` option comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Portable to most shells, avoid error with one file (using only `seq` and shell given `printf`, `set` and `eval`):

```
set -- *
[ $# -gt 1 ] && eval set -- "$(printf "\"\${%s}\" " $(seq "$#" -1 1))"
printf '%s '   "$@"
```

It is reasonable to set nullglob and failglob where available.