# macOS bash script regular expression not working as expected

Tags: bash, scripting, regular-expression, macos

I've been out of programming for more than 10 years. I have a text file that I'm trying to read the Mpbs value for the upload and download speed.

```
     Server: Iomart - Maidenhead (id = 3839)
        ISP: Plusnet
    Latency:     8.59 ms   (0.10 ms jitter)
   Download:    71.43 Mbps (data used: 52.8 MB)                               
     Upload:    18.39 Mbps (data used: 16.9 MB)                               
Packet Loss:     0.0%
```

I've been using a regex tool to test and build my regex, which delivers the result I want.

```bsh
regex2="Upload:\W+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"
regex3="Download:\W+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"

while read line; do  
    if [[ $line =~ regex2 ]]
    then
        echo  "match ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        UPS=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi  
    if [[ $line =~ regex3 ]]
    then
    echo  "match ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        DNS=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi 
done < Result.txt
```

I'm sure there must be a better way to achieve what I want, but the main problem I'm having is the regex not working.

Comment: You are trying to match against the literal `regex2` and `regex3`, I think you want `$regex2` and `$regex3`.

Comment: oops.. Thanks very much. That was a bad cut and paste. now the problem is the \W+ doesn't work. If i just leave the correct number of spaces(four in this case) in the regex2 variable it'll match. is \W or \s not the right way to go? i've tried using \ \\ \\\ and \\\\

Comment: `\W` is a PCRE feature - `bash` only claims to support ERE. I suspect that (especially on MacOS) the bash version doesn't recognize `\W` (or treats it as literal `W`). You could consider using `[[:blank:]]` instead to match horizontal whitespace (unless you specifically expect other non-word characters between the `:` and the number)

Comment: ... see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: The PCRE `\W` is the same as POSIX `[^[:alnum:]_]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have three issues in your code.

1. You're not using the regular expressions you think you are (missing `$` on `regex2` and `regex3`).
2. `bash` does not understand the Perl-like regular expression `\W` as "not a word character".
3. You are not reading lines (even though your variable is called `line`).

To solve this:

1. Use `$` on to get the values of `regex2` and `regex3` in the tests:

   ```
   if [[ $line =~ $regex2 ]]; then ...; fi
   ```
2. Use the POSIX regular expression `[^[:alnum:]_]` in place of `\W` in the expressions, or `[[:blank:]]` which matches a tab or space.
3. Use `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done` (see "[Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)").

Comment: Thank you, one and all.

Comment: @StewartRolfe You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).