# Shell Script to trim if else condition

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am getting successful output when i run below script. What i am trying here is, i should connect to all below VM's listed and when script ssh to `wasadmds03` then it should print output as `product detail`, similarly for other VM's and also it should execute the command 
**"cat /source/package.json | grep version"** on all VM's.

I am getting the output what i need - but is there a way to trim the repeated "if then" statement? I have used "if then" statement four times, imagine if i want to do the similar exercise for 50 VM's is there a way to write this program in a shorter way?

```
wasadmds03 - product detail
wasadmds04 - product list
wasadmls03 - Cart
wasadmls05 - checkout
```

- Script

**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /tmp/ms_test`
do
        if [ $i = wasadmds03 ]
        then
            echo "Product Detail"
            ssh $i "cat /source/package.json | grep version"
        fi
        if [ $i = wasadmds04 ]
        then
            echo "Product list"
            ssh $i "cat /source/package.json | grep version"
        fi
        if [ $i = wasadmls03 ]
        then
            echo "Merchant"
            ssh $i "cat /source/package.json | grep version"
        fi
        if [ $i = wasadmls05 ]
        then
            echo "Account Details"
            ssh $i "cat /source/package.json | grep version"
        fi
done
```

Comment: Hi - Can someone assist on this request?

Comment: What's in `/tmp/ms_test`?

Comment: At least I would use elif instead of fi;if so that it will test all case before going out the loop. But yes I wonder too what is in the /tmp/ms_test file.

Comment: /tmp/ms_test file contains VM names..(wasadmds03 ,wasadmds04 ,wasadmls03  etc..)

Comment: Eventhough if i use elseif - suppose if i am checking this for 50 VM's, will it have 50 else if conditions? any shorter ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue seems to be that you'd like to output a specific label depending on the host name read from the file.

We can certainly compact the code somewhat. If we store the text label that should be different for each host in an associative array, we can end up with just

```
printf '%s\n' "${labels[$remote]}"
ssh -n "$remote" 'cat /source/package.json' | jq -r .version
```

... inside the loop.

Here, I've taken the liberty of renaming the `i` loop variable to `remote` which is much more descriptive.  I'm also using `printf` instead of `echo` (see "[Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)"), and I chose to parse that JSON data file using a real JSON parser, `jq`, rather than with `grep` (this also means that I'm just *guessing* that there is a top-level `version` key in the JSON data).

`ssh` must be called with `ssh -n` so that it doesn't read the input that the loop we're using iterates over.

The `labels` array may be created like so:

```
declare -A labels
labels=(
    ['wasadmds03']='Product Detail'
    ['wasadmds04']='Product List'
    ['wasadmls03']='Merchant'
    ['wasadmls05']='Account Details'
)
```

Note that if you have more remote host names, these should be listed in this array in a similar way.  You will need to list each one since you don't provide this data in any other way.

This, together with properly reading the remote host names from `/tmp/ms_test` (see "[Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)") gives us the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A labels
labels=(
    ['wasadmds03']='Product Detail'
    ['wasadmds04']='Product List'
    ['wasadmls03']='Merchant'
    ['wasadmls05']='Account Details'
)

while IFS= read -r remote; do
    printf '%s\n' "${labels[$remote]}"
    ssh -n "$remote" 'cat /source/package.json' | jq -r .version
done </tmp/ms_test
```

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda it worked!!!!