# What does junk do in this script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I received this linux script from my professor and I was trying to understand what it does and I think I know what most of it does. However, there is one part that confuses me. What does `junk` do in this line:

```
who | while read user junk
```

What's its purpose? I've tried googling it but I just can't seem to find it anywhere other than referencing junk characters and from what I can tell that's a separate thing. The whole script is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Run a while loop using input of user command
who | while read user junk
do
   #Get users real name from /etc/passwd file
   realname=`grep $user /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5`
   echo "User: $realname ($user)"
   #Get user's logged in time using who command
   loggedin=`who | grep $user | awk '{print $3" "$4}'`
   echo "Logged in: $loggedin"
   #Get home directory of the user from /etc/passwd file
   homedir=`cat /etc/passwd | grep $user | cut -d":" -f6`
   echo "Home Directory is $homedir"
   #Get count of all files in user's home directory
   #including sub-directories (excluding directory count) using find command
   file_dir_count=`find $homedir -type f | wc -l`
   echo "Home directory contains $file_dir_count files"
   #Get user's processes count using ps command
   proc_count=`ps -u $user --no-headers | wc -l`
   echo "$user has $proc_count processes"
   #Display user's top 7 memory using process list in given order using top
   echo "Top 7 processes sorted by Memory Usage:"
   top -b -n 1 -u $user -o %MEM | head -14 | tail -8 | awk '!($3="")'
done
```

Comment: `junk` is a variable name. If you enter `foo bar baz`, `read user junk` will assign `foo` to `user` and `bar baz` to `junk`. He probably called it `junk` because he ignores its value, and cares only about the first word entereded by the user. As to the rest of the script -- find a better professor ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `read` is used in your script means that it will read the first word on each line in the output of `who` into the variable `user`, and *the rest of the line* (from the first space or tab) into the variable `junk`.

By default, `read` reads words delimited by any character in `$IFS` (space, tab, newline) into each of the listed variables.  The last variable listed will get what is left of the data after assigning words to the previous variables.

This is a cheap way of reading only the first word on each line.

See "[Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)" for more details.

---

The script has *several* issues.  It will, for example, give you incorrect results (and quite likely errors) if there are users with usernames that are substrings of each other, like `bill` and `billy`.  It will also produce the wrong results if a user has files with filenames that contain newlines.

It also executes `who` *again* for each user, even though this information could well have been read with the initial `read`.  It also reads `/etc/passwd` several times per line of output of that initial `who` command.

I would suggest dividing the processing up into an information gathering section (which uses a single `getent passwd "$user"` call to get the `passwd` info, and which does *not* use `top` which is primarily an interactive monitoring tool) and a separate reporting section (for output). Using whitespace (like, empty lines) would also improve readability.