# while read loop not working inside alias

Tags: bash, command, alias, echo, read

In Bash, the following command

```
echo foo | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

outputs `foo`; however, the following

```
alias bar="echo foo | while read line; do echo $line; done"
bar
```

outputs a `\n` (or empty space). What is causing this difference in behavior?

Comment: Use a shell function instead, then you won't have issues with quoting. Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123 (about using `read` correctly) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694 (about quoting correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes to defer variable expansion:

```
alias bar='echo foo | while read line; do echo $line; done'
```