# How to EXCLUDE copying files that start with DOT "." in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I had followed several threads here in SO to copy files from one directory to another. I am using  inotifywait for my purposes which is working perfectly for all BUT one scenario. It's also copying files that start with a DOT prefix (ex .tmp.swp) which I don't want.

I tried this but this even causing files with the `-json` postfix to NOT get copied.
I don't want `.tmp.abcd-json` to be copied. If I remove the check AFTER the `&&` everything is getting copied over including the `.tmp.abcd-json`:

These are some of the contents of the directory. The `.tmp` ones are unwanted but it's not ALWAYS guaranteed they will always start with `.tmp`. I've seen other files start with `.` prefixes randomly which also need to be ignored:-

`abcd-json`
`.tmp.abcd-json`

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=/var/lib/docker/containers
target=/var/log/splunkf
inotifywait -m -r "$dir" --format '%w%f' -e create -e modify  \
| while read file;
        do
                if [[ $file == "-json"* ]] && [[ $file != "."* ]];
                then
                    echo Copying  $file to $target
                    cp -- "$file" "$target";
                else
                    echo NOT Copying  $file to $target
                fi
        done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match with `RegEx` for files **NOT** starting with `dot` in your `if` condition as:

```
while read file;
        do
          f="$(basename -- $file)"
          if ! [[ "$f" =~ ^\. ]];
          then
             echo Copying  $file to $target
             cp -- "$file" "$target";
          else
             echo NOT Copying  $file to $target
          fi
```

Comment: thanks!! The NOT was habitual (coming from C# :) ). However, this didn't work. I still see all these files which includes the undesirable! ```-rw-r-----.  1 root root 385710 Jan 25 19:40 82adf74ac58a5f29ae539b8ebbee360b21dda11e1c4767e4696ad264cb9a558f-json.log
-rw-------.  1 root root   7185 Jan 25 19:40 .tmp-config.v2.json162008322```

Comment: Logs are  showing it copying both the ones start with `.` and ones without. ```Copying /var/lib/docker/containers/a7079968c23e9da10a1969c7eb343a98e12ea685f8b3f3d2834666b0df5ab8c8/.tmp-hostconfig.json847502457 to /var/log/splunkf```

Comment: @DorianMcAllister yes, because the content of `$file` is the whole absolute path of file, which of course will never start with a dot and always starts with `/`.

Comment: So we should search for the LAST instance of `/` and find if a file starts with `.`? any suggestions how we can do that?

Comment: @DorianMcAllister yes, I updated the answer. with `basename` it's easily possible.

Comment: Huzzah!! That did it. Clean and elegant@

Comment: Note that `! [[ $f == .* ]]` would also work.  There's no need for a regular expression match.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is not the use of a pattern match in `[[ ... ]]`.  It's the fact that the string that you get in `$file` is a pathname that contains a directory path at the start of it, i.e. the pattern `.*` would only ever match it if the directory path `$dir` started with a dot.

You also seems to run the script with `/bin/sh` rather than with `bash`, so you would not necessarily expect any of the `[[ ... ]]` test to work at all.

---

To exclude filename patterns matched by `inotifywait`, use `--exclude 'PATTERN'`.  For example:

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create -e modify \
        --exclude '/\.[^/]*$' "$dir"
```

The pattern used with `--exclude` here matches any pathname that ends with a filename that starts with a dot.  These would not be reported by `inotifywait`.

When using `--exclude` with `inotifywait`,  your code collapses into

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

dir=/var/lib/docker/containers
target=/var/log/splunkf

inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create -e modify \
        --exclude '/\.[^/]*$' "$dir" |
xargs -I {} cp -- {} "$target"
```

This obviously assumes that no filename contains newlines.

---

Would you want to use a loop in `bash` with an explicit test and diagnostic output, you could use

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dir=/var/lib/docker/containers
target=/var/log/splunkf

inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create -e modify "$dir" |
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    if [[ ${pathname##*/} == .* ]]; then
        printf 'Not copying "%s"\n' "$pathname" >&2
    else
        printf 'Copying "%s" to "%s"\n' "$pathname" "$target" >&2
        cp -- "$pathname" "$target"
    fi
done
```

Note the use of `IFS= read -r`.  This is to prevent stripping flanking whitespace from the filenames and to avoid interpreting backslash sequences (see [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)).

With `/bin/sh`, you would do

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

dir=/var/lib/docker/containers
target=/var/log/splunkf

inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e create -e modify "$dir" |
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    case ${pathname##*/} in
        .*)
            printf 'Not copying "%s"\n' "$pathname" >&2
            ;;
        *)
            printf 'Copying "%s" to "%s"\n' "$pathname" "$target" >&2
            cp -- "$pathname" "$target"
    esac
done
```