# destructured assignment by splitting on newlines zsh

Tags: zsh

I have a command that outputs 2 lines,

```
% ./run
one
two
%
```

so the output is `one\ntwo\n`

How can I assign variables `first` and `second` to the first and second lines respectively?

I know how I could do both by running the command twice:

```
% first="$(./run | head -n 1)"
% second="$(./run | tail -n 1)"
```

I don't want to run `./run` twice, I only want to call it once (output might be different each time)

I could just store `./run`'s output in a variable, then operate on the variable, but can I avoid having this temporary variable?

More and more high-level languages are adding destructuring assignments:

```
first, second = (./run).split('\n')
```

Can I accomplish something similar in zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read each line with a separate call to `read`.

```
IFS= read -r first
IFS= read -r second
```

For example:

```
$ unset first second
$ printf 'one\ntwo\n' | { IFS= read -r first; IFS= read -r second; }
$ print $first
one
$ print $second
two
```

The above works only because `zsh` does not run the right hand side of the pipeline in a separate subshell.

Or, with a process substitution:

```
$ unset first second
$ { IFS= read -r first; IFS= read -r second; } < <( printf 'one\ntwo\n' )
$ print $first
one
$ print $second
two
```

See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Comment: How bad is this code? I'm learning `zsh`: `vars=(first second);c=1;for i in $(./cmd); do typeset "${vars[$c]}"="$i"; ((c++)); done`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I would call it mostly unreadable, and therefore unmaintainable, at least in a professional setting. I can see what it _does_, but I can immediately say that it's _correct_.  Seeing as we loop over `read` all the time (`while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done`), I see no reason to not do an "unrolled loop" of two `read` calls when we know that we want to read exactly two values.