# How to split line in for loop and use as arguments to command line call

Tags: bash

I have a seemingly very simple problem but I am unable to come up with a satisfying solution.
I have a simple input file containing IPs and ports, like

```
10.155.78.0 445
172.17.11.0 3389
```

Now I want to execute `nc -vvv <ip> <port>` for each line in a for loop.

All I can come up with is splitting the line twice with cut:

```
for x in $(cat inputfile); do nc -vvv $(echo -n $x | cut -d" " -f1) $(echo -n $x | cut -d" " -f2)
```

or using gawk and starting a sub-shell

```
for x in $(cat dingens); do cmd=$(echo $x | gawk -F" " '{ print "nc -vvv -w 2 " $1 " " $2 }'); echo -n $cmd | bash; done
```

but both solutions seem terribly complicated.
Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: [Don't read the lines of a file with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
while IFS=" " read -r Ip Port Junk <&3; do
    nc -vvv "${Ip}" "${Port}" 3<&-
done 3< inFile
```

The purpose of `Junk` is to receive any fields after the second (for example, a comment). We open `inFile` on fd 3 instead of stdin as otherwise `nc`, invoked within that loop would also end up reading the contents of `inFile`

Comment: btw, running commands based on the contents of a file is, at least to me, one of the cases where it's _not_ a bad habit to process text in a shell loop. Even if it [often is in other cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169765#169765).

Comment: See also e.g. [Understanding “IFS= read -r line”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/170373) for what the `IFS=` setting and `-r` do.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `xargs`, e.g.:

```
xargs -n 2 nc -vvv < inputfile
```

From `man xargs`:

> `-n max-args`, `--max-args=max-args`
>
> Use  at most max-args arguments per command line. [...]

You can even use `xargs` to run multiple `nc` commands in parallel using the `-P` option, as long as you're careful about redirecting the output of each.  e.g. if you had an 8-core CPU and wanted to run 8 `nc` jobs in parallel:

```
xargs -P 8 -n 2 sh -c 'nc -vvv "$1" "$2" > "$1-$2.log"' sh < inputfile
```

> `-P max-procs`, `--max-procs=max-procs`
>
> Run up to `max-procs` processes at a time; the default is 1. [...]

Comment: But then, depending on the `xargs` implementation, `nc`'s stdin will either also be `inputFile` or `/dev/null`. With GNU `xargs`, you could use `-a inputFile` so that `nc`'s stdin be left untouched and only `xargs` reads `inputFile`.

Comment: `< inputfile` belongs to xargs, because it's being redirected by the shell running xargs.   `nc` is being run by xargs, so it doesn't/shouldn't get its parent's stdin - unless, as you suggest, `xargs -a` is used. in that case, xargs is free to pass on its stdin to its child process (but that's still kind of weird and likely to be broken because it might have several children)

Comment: GNU `xargs cmd` opens `cmd`'s stdin on `/dev/null`, some other `xargs` implementations don't. In those that don't, `nc` will inherit `xargs` stdin and since `nc` does read its stdin (to send to the remote service it's connecting to), `nc` would consume the contents of `inputFile` that has not already been read by `xargs`.

Comment: GNU xargs does the right thing.  those other implementations are, IMO, broken.   If you want to use xargs to run a program that needs to read stdin, wrap it in `sh -c` or similar and pipe something into it in that.   There's really no call for any cmd executed by xargs to be consuming xargs' own stdin - that would seem to be a good way to experience a race-condition.