# If using while read loops for text processing in bash is bad...what should I do, then?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I guess this may be a naive question but I can't get my head around so I felt like asking...
I was searching for some solution to a problem, when I found [this very interesting post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169720) about why is using `[while|for]` loops in bash considered bad practice. There is a very good explanation in the post (see the chosen answer) but I can't find anything that solves the issues that are discussed.

I searched extensively: I googled (or duckduckgo-ed) `how to read a file in bash` and all the results I am getting point towards a solution that, according to the above-mentioned post, is absolutely non-bash style and something that should be avoided. In particular, we have this:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line | cut -c3
done
```

and this:

```
for line in `cat file`; do
  foo=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
  echo whatever $foo
done
```

that are indicated as very bad examples of shell scripting. At this point I am wondering, and this is the actual question: if the posted while loops should be avoided because they are bad practice and whatever...what am I supposed to do, instead?

EDIT: I see that I am already having comments/questions addressing the exact issue with the `while` loop, so I feel like to widen the question a bit. Basically, what I am understanding is that I need to dig deeper into bash commands, and that is the real thing that I should do. But, when one searches around, it looks like people are, in the general case, using and teaching bash in an improper way (as per my google-ing).

Comment: Regarding your examples: use `cut`  or `awk` on the file directly. In general: There is no general answer.

Comment: The other question shows the alternatives when it's explaining why you shouldn't use shell loops.

Comment: My own solution:  Use Perl for anything more than a simple list of commands.

Comment: I suggest to change the title. As it stands now, people see "If using while loops in bash is bad ..." in places like the Hot Network Questions. Things like this lead to public myths that ... using while loops in bash is bad, and might have bad influence on bash newbies. Which is nonsense. The question you linked shows a particular usage of while loops which is indeed bad, but the problem is not the while loop itself, at all, but directly translating programming practices from lower level general languages and ignoring the piping mechanism of shells.

Comment: @AnoE what do you suggest, then?

Comment: @gabt: Use your actual question (from your second-to-last paragraph, for example "How to read a file line-by-line"). (This may or may not be a duplicate to some other question). Or if you do indeed want to focus on the `while`, then ask it like "What is a proper usage of the while statement".

Comment: @AnoE, ok. I guess I can come up with something better and I hope I did it...

Comment: Perfect, thanks. ;)

Comment: I rolled back your change, gabt. @AnoE please dont' tell users to make a change that completely alters the question being asked after people have already posted answers. The change you suggested renders existing answers irrelevant and also makes this question a direct duplicate of [the one already linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169720). The answers there perfectly explain why it's a bad idea to use the shell for this and also cover the safest way of doing it.

Comment: Lol, @terdon. If it makes you happy. I did not "tell users"; I made a suggestion. For me, it is more worth it to avoid a SE question promoting confusion and wrong information (right now, if you google "bash while loop bad", this question already pops up at position first, and again, due to the way the title is formulated, the first thing a newbie reads is that while loops are bad). I am aware of the content and the answers, but the message in the title is what people are reading in HNQ, search results or google hits.

Comment: @AnoE you're right, you did not "tell", you were perfectly polite and just made a suggestion. Sorry, I shouldn't have phrased that so aggressively, I didn't mean you did anything really wrong. It's just that as a general rule, we really don't like it when an edit renders existing answers obsolete. That said, the question title never promotes wrong information! It's a question, not an answer, that's kind of the point. We often see things like (absurd example) "Why are napkins stronger when wet?" with answers explaining that the premise is wrong. Nothing bad about that.

Comment: Is "don't use bash" an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The point of the post you linked to is to explain that *using bash to parse text files is a bad idea in general*. It isn't specifically about using loops and there is nothing intrinsically wrong with shell loops in other contexts. Nobody is saying that a shell script with `while` is somehow bad. That other post is saying that you shouldn't try to parse text files using the shell and you should instead use other tools.

To clarify, when I say "using the shell" I mean using the shell's internal tools to open the file, extract the data and parse it. For example something like this:

```
while read number; do
  if [ $number -gt 10 ]; then
    echo "The number '$number' is greater than 10"
  else
    echo "The number '$number' is less than or equal to 10"
done < numbers.txt
```

Please read the answers at [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169720) for details on why this sort of thing is a bad idea. Here, I will only clarify that that post isn't arguing against shell loops in general, but against using shell loops (or the shell) for parsing files.

The reason you don't find suggestions for better ways of doing it with bash is that there are no good ways of doing this with bash or any other shell. No matter what you do, parsing text using a shell will be slow, cumbersome, and error prone.

Shells are primarily designed as a way of entering commands to be run by the computer. They can be used as scripting languages but, again, they are at their best when given commands to run and *not* when used *instead* of commands designed to handle text parsing.

Shells are tools and just like any other tool, they should be used for the purpose they were designed for. The problem is that many people have learned a little bit of shell scripting, so they have a tool, a "hammer". Because all they know is a hammer, every problem they encounter looks like a nail to them and they try and use their hammer on this nail. Sadly, parsing text is not something that the shell was designed to handle, it isn't a "nail", so using a "hammer" is just not a good idea.

So, the answer to "how should I read a file in bash" is very simply "you should not use bash and instead use a tool that is appropriate for the job".

Comment: I find that answer confusing and a bit misleading. `cut -c3 < file` and  `while read line; do echo $line | cut -c 3; done` are two samples of bash code (bash being a shell, a tool whose purpose is to run other tools), the first one running one invocation of one text utility, the second one 3 incorrect invocations of 2 clunky tools and a text processing utility for each line of the file in a loop. Shells are designed to run tools some of which are good at processing text, what it being discussed here is how and which tools and how, not whether bash should be used to invoke them.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sorry, which answer? This one? The OP had misunderstood your answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169720) as saying that using shell loops is bad in general. I am clarifying that no, the point of your answer was that using shells to parse text files is a bad idea, loops are not the issue. Using shells to invoke _other_ tools is fine, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "this" answer (yours). The problem is not about using shells to process text, but using shells that way (with a loop calling many invocations of clunky tools, and here incorrectly) as opposed to one invocation of a text processing tool (or of several tools cooperating in a pipeline).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes. Also with using shells at all though. I mean things like `if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]` and the like, and pitfalls with `while read` etc. Far better to use the shell to call other tools that can handle this sort of thing better. I am addressing someone who wants to write a parser using the shell as a scripting language instead of using something like awk or sed or perl or python etc. Even in the best case scenario, as you explain so well in your answer, the shell approach will be horribly slow compared to anything else.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I edited to make my point clearer. I hope that makes more sense now.

Comment: @terdon: StéphaneChazelas is objecting to the way you use phrases such as "using bash to parse text files": you're using them to mean something like `while read line; do echo $line | cut -c 3; done` as opposed to something like `cut -c3 < file`, but he contends that such phrases do *not* distinguish between those examples, because both are examples of using Bash and `cut`. He's not disagreeing with your point that one of these is a bad idea and one of them is a good idea, he's just objecting to the phrasing you're using to convey that point.

Comment: @ruakh: What would you think about adding the adverb "piecemeal": one shouldn't use shells to process text files *piecemeal*; instead, one should use the shell to direct other programs to perform larger groups of operations.

Comment: @supercat: I'm not sure. Honestly, I was fine with terdon's phrasing; I had to read StéphaneChazelas' comments a few times to understand his point, and while I'm sure that he's technically correct, I don't see a simple way to address it without making the answer more confusing for those who'd need it.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using a shell `while` or `for` loop that calls `awk` **once for each line**, just run awk once, giving it the filename as an argument.  e.g.

```
awk '{print "whatever " $2}' file
```

same with `cut`:

```
cut -c3 file
```

If you need to do further processing **in bash** on each line returned by awk, your best option is to use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to populate an array.

```
myarray=( $(awk '{print $2}' file) )
```

It's important to **not** double-quote the command substitution here because we **want** the shell's word-splitting to occur - each element of the array will be one "word" and, as awk's input is whitespace-separated and it only prints one field, it will output one "word" per line.

Alternatively, you can use the bash built-in `readarray` aka `mapfile` along with [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
mapfile -t myarray < <(awk '{print $2}' file)
```

The `mapfile`/`readarray` variant is required if the input contains glob patterns like `*` in $2, otherwise the shell will try to expand the glob.

Once you have the data in an array, you can iterate over it with a for loop, e.g.:

```
for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do do_something_with "$i"; done
```

or pass it as args to another program or built-in:

```
printf "whatever %s\n" "${myarray[@]}"
```

Note, however, that you will almost always be better off doing any extra processing in awk.  This may mean re-designing and re-writing your bash script so that most of the work is done in awk.  Or rewriting the whole thing as an awk script if it turns out that bash isn't needed.   ditto for perl. and python. and other languages.

shell is a good language for orchestrating **other** programs to process data and do actual work, but is terrible at doing data processing work itself - almost any other language would be better than shell for processing data.

If you find yourself moving data back and forth between shell and awk or some other language, that's a good sign that you need to rewrite the whole thing in awk (or whatever).

Comment: So, just to clarify your answer (which I find interesting)...what you are suggesting is that `[awk|sed|R|python]` are those programs that I can use, throughout some shell script, to make what I would do with the `while` loop (or a `for` loop). I always thought that shell scripting was used for doing things with files, characters, strings, and fields but I guess I must rethink my way of doing stuff.

Comment: @gabt the shell is a great tool for manipulating files, yes. Not their contents, usually, but the files themselves (think copying, moving, organizing into directories etc.). But it is a horrible tool for _parsing_ the files or doing anything with strings or fields.

Comment: @gabt - yep, what terdon said.

Comment: @terdon so...I need to clarify this point: I am thinking about `grep`, `cut` and `tr`, just to make three examples of _programs_ that work with the content of files. Should they be replaced with something that is specifically designed for doing what they do? Because to me, using them, means working with bash to do things with file content.

Comment: grep, cut, and tr **are** tools specifically designed to do particular jobs.   you use grep, for example, instead of writing a bash while-read loop to do a regex or fixed string match against each line of the file.   `grep pattern file` is the way to do it, **not** `while read line ; do [[ $line =~ pattern ]] && echo $line ; done < file`

Comment: also, while what terdon said about bash being great for manipulating files is true, it's also true that mostly bash will do that by getting other programs (like `mv`, `cp`, `tar`, and many more including `grep`, `cut`, `awk`, `perl`, etc etc etc) to do the actual work.    bash's number one job is to feed data to other programs via comand-line arguments or by setting up pipes from one to another.

Comment: @cas allright, so, in that specific example, i.e. using the while loop for reading the file line by line, the loop was _not_ _the_ _best_ _choice_ just because there is something better that was designed for doing it. that was the whole point.

Comment: Exactly yes. The loop is irrelevant, the point is that the _shell_ is not the right tool. Grep, cut, awk, perl, sed, etc are not part of the shell. And, as cas correctly pointed out, neither are `mv`, `cp` and their ilk. The point is that the shell is designed to, as cas put it very nicely, orchestrate other programs to process data and do actual work, and isn't good at doing the work itself.

Comment: @gabt Bash (and other shells) `read` is designed to be used to read a small amount of input (typically a user response in the terminal), not to read a whole file. It may use a system call for each line or for each byte, which is very inefficient compared to what awk or sed do. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/88378 And on top of that, if you're doing anything more complicated than trying to detect a simple pattern, parsing text in Bash gets very messy very quickly.

Comment: `array=( $(anything) )` is itself an antipattern. See [BashPittfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29). `readarray -t array < <(anything)` is a better alternative for bash 4.0 or newer, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array < <(anything && printf '\0')` for older bash versions (and to make `read`'s exit status tell whether `anything` succeeded).

Comment: @PM2Ring, ...a syscall per line would be great if it was possible, but the `read` syscall gets only a specific number of bytes to consume; there's no way to make it stop at the next newline without reading a byte at a time and checking whether that byte was in fact a newline. Languages with semantics that allow buffering can go that route, but that's not the case with shell languages, where the file descriptor is expected to be queued up right after the read content so subprocesses can pick up at the point where `read` left off.

Comment: Thanks, @Charles. I've always thought that `read` was forced to make one syscall per byte, but the post I linked seems to imply that some shells can (somehow) read with line buffering, so I figured I should mention that possibility. ;)

Answer (score 13):

The thing to avoid in your examples isn’t the looping, it’s the pointless use of multiple invocations of commands. It just happens that looping is one of the most common causes of useless invocations of commands in shell scripts (the other big one is not remembering to just use redirection).

Starting a new process is one of the most expensive operations possible on almost any system, so efficient scripts (and efficient code in general) keep the total number of processes to a minimum. This efficiency limitation is a large part of why `inetd` has fallen out of favor, and why many web servers default to starting a bunch of long-lived processes and handing connections to them as needed instead of spawning a process per connection on-demand.

Both of your examples can be reduced to starting a *single* process for the whole operation. The first one thus would become:

```bsh
cut -c3
```

And the second would instead be:

```bsh
awk '{print $2}'` < file
```

Not only are those more efficient, they’re also more readable.

This is not to say that looping in general is bad, just that a lot of things you might use it for in other languages don’t require it in shell scripts because the tools involved inherently process multiple lines or files. A good example of something it *would* be valid to use it for is handling of multiple attempts at doing something (assuming that the ‘something’ does not inherently support retries).

Comment: so, the idea here is that the `while` loop in the original question calls many commands, i.e. `grep`, or `echo`..., for each loop. While (!), if I use `awk` then pipe it's output to `grep`, `sed`, or whatever, this would be much more efficient (and readable and everything).

Comment: @gabt Essentially yes, both in terms of the number of processes involved, and possibly in terms of memory usage (though that’s less clear and really dependent on a bunch of other factors). In general, almost all traditional UNIX command-line tools are designed to process whole files at a time, operating on a line-by-line basis, so it’s relatively rare that you need a loop in shell script to actually do this type of thing.

Comment: @gabt You can also considering writing a `perl` script that reads a file line-by-line in a loop, does the same transformations that `sed`, `awk` or whatever would do, but _using perl internal functions and not by calling external programs_ and writes the modified line back to output file. Perl is a language designed just for processing text files. And if you need, you can also call system commands like `cp` from within Perl.

Comment: @raj, yes I am actually reading around to understand which tool is worth learning to work with files and I surely considered perl. There are way too many tools and it's not that easy to choose one that works for everything (also I don't think such a thing exists). But, at least, I am now moving from bad shell scripting to, hopefully, something better.

Comment: @gabt My personal suggestion would be to look to Python. It’s designed for more generalized usage than PERL was, is far more powerful than shell script, and is much easier to learn than either.

Comment: The language name is _Perl_ (not PERL), and its implementation executable is called `perl`.  Perl 5 is much faster than Python, and Perl 6 is compiled to the JVM or other VM and is as fast as Java etc.  Which is easier to learn depends on your background:  moving from Bash/AWK/sed, Perl will be quite natural as it rolls up those tools in particular (among others).  If you're basing your work on regex, Perl is more seamless than other languages.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct, I just wonder if it's difficult to understand the concepts they are conveying. So I want to present you with a metaphor. Hopefully it makes sense:

You can consider the shell script as like a conductor. The conductor points at different musicians to indicate they should start or stop playing, play louder or softer, faster or slower. The conductor themselves doesn't step down into the orchestra to start playing an instrument; neither does the conductor "micro-manage" the musician by telling them how to turn the pages of their music sheets. The conductor trusts the musician to do that work themselves. The conductor just instructs the musicians when to play and how to play.

You shell script is like this. It is orchestrating a lot of other commands. It is not directly manipulating files at all. Even when you use a command like `mv` or `cp`, those commands are doing the actual work. They are like the musicians. The shell script says to the `mv` "musician" — move this here — and it does it. The shell script doesn't move the file itself. It lets the `mv` command do it.

Also, just like the conductor doesn't tell the musician when to turn the page, the shell script doesn't need to feed a file one line at a time to a command. It can give the whole file to the command and tell it what to do with it. Thus there is no need for a loop. The loop shouldn't be used to micro-manage the command, it should be used to orchestrate multiple commands over multiple files.

Don't forget that "commands" in shell scripts are not like commands in other languages — they are not keywords that form the shell script's language. Rather they are all separate programs that can be run from the shell. `cp`, for example is a program of its own. That program copies files. It has its own manual and a list of arguments you can pass to it. You can run `cp` from a shell (outside a script) and all you are doing is calling a program called `cp`. In the same way you could create your own programs (by creating shell scripts) and call them from within your shell script.

Hope that helped to explain it a bit.

Comment: yes, I guess that one thing to keep in mind, as you mentioned, is that _commands_ are not function of the shell language but actual programs that do things. I guess I knew that (at some level) but, in practice, I've never used these commands as I should have.

Comment: Very poetic analogy.  I never thought of cp as its own program, either.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing this answer from a pragmatic perspective. I don't think using loops in Bash is necessarily bad.

A big benefit of using scripting languages like Bash is to realize tasks that come to your mind as quickly and easily as possible. Bash enables this by providing you the ability to combine small, efficient, general purpose programs like cat, cut, head, grep, tee, etc. via pipes. One would prefer using a Bash one-liner that makes use of a set of already efficient programs (like `grep <something> input-file | cut -c3`) rather than writing a program from scratch that does the same job, most of the case even it is slower.

If you roughly know what Bash can offer you, meaning you know sufficient amount of basic unix programs, Bash's piping features and programming language structures, and if it still is convenient to use loops, just do it.

Comment: Doing that `grep pattern file | cut` isn't bad. That's using the tools for what they're meant for. But wrapping that command in a shell loop and running `grep` and `cut` for each individual line is just silly.

Answer (score -1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the examples you gave. No, they aren't using processing time efficiently. But that's fine in many circumstances. Only start optimizing once it's actually beneficial. And when you start to have a real need for optimization, you are probably best off dumping bash entirely and using a proper language instead. It's also worth it to learn how to mix bash with your high level language of choice so you can leverage the best of both worlds.

Comment: a long way to go ;-)

Comment: What do you mean? It's really easy to mix, for example Bash+Python works like a charm and is 10 times easier than learning to use all the obscure shell tools that might enable to stay within bash.

Comment: yes, but I am finding it hard to do things with python that I found easy with _bad_ bash scripting!

Comment: @Nobody, there's lots wrong with those examples. Yes, bash's I/O features are slow (by necessity, f/e, `read` _can't_ buffer input and needs to read one byte at a time so file descriptors are left queued up for other processes to inherit and take over without needing to hand off the buffer content), but if you use bash well you don't _need_ to care if those features are slow; all the work is done by the programs you're calling, not by bash itself. This is an orders-of-magnitude performance difference, more than enough to make the difference between "bash is good enough" and "must rewrite"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, but it's not worth it to learn all the details of bash and awk etc. when you could learn how to do it much easier and faster in a high level language. Once something is performance critical, bash is just not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Nobody, ...but it's perfectly fine to use bash to _start_ a performance-critical component, as long as what matters is the performance after the component is already running, right? That's what the linked question's answers are telling people to do: Use bash to start programs written in faster languages _and let those programs written in faster languages do the looping_, instead of writing logic that makes bash start a subprocess for every line/record/etc.

Comment: @Nobody, ...btw, I'd also argue that awk _is_ a higher-level language itself (and certainly it doesn't have the spec/design limitations that force shell-native IO to be slow). For a reasonable subset of use cases it's just as capable as perl or python.

Comment: @gabt, btw, helping folks go from bad bash to good bash is something I do a lot of over at Stack Overflow. Mind, `while read` isn't itself always bad -- it's slow, but not horrible. Putting `var=$(echo "$line" | awk ...)` or `var=$(echo "$line" | cut ...)` inside that loop, on the other, hand, _that's_ horrible.

Comment: @gabt Maybe you need to learn to program better, or maybe it's just that for example you need to know how to use the subprocess module. If you have an existing script you can paste parts of it into subproces invocations (like `r=subprocess.run("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep bugs", shell=True, capture_output=True)`) and then access its stdout, stderr or return code from python. You can also feed something to the standard input by using arguments text=True and input=SomeStringOrBytesObject. The commands you can use to get better performance from "within" the shell (like awk) are much harder to use

Comment: and are less powerful and useful. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: yep, I am actually working with python to parse files in a meaningful way so that they can be analysed easily. that is the solution I found that works for me.