# in AIX ksh the command "mail" reads from STDIN and stops a loop wherein it is

Tags: email, ksh, stdin

using ksh on an AIX 7.2 system

I have the following inputfile:

```
line1   
line2  
line3
```

I have the following code (rather simplified)

```
cat infile | while read strA ; do  
    echo "strA: $strA"  
    mail -s"check script strA: $strA" me@mailserver.com  
done
```

"mail" seems to read from STDIN, what stops the loop after the first line.
Result is:

```
line1  
=>sending mail
```

When I let "mail" read from /dev/null, it works:

```
mail -s"check script strA: $strA" me@mailserver.com </dev/null
```

**BUT** this way I get Warnings "No Message Body"

When I give a not empty dummyfile it also works`

```
   mail -s"check script strA: $strA" me@mailserver.com </tmp/anyexistingfile
```

**BUT** I do not want to send some rubbish

Is there another way to prevent reading from STDIN and exiting the loop?
Any secret mail-option? (I can't find some)

Thank you very much in advance

*(hmmm ... took me 10 minutes to describe the problem and 20 minutes to format the text)*

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to send in those emails.

Comment: You can always do `echo See subject. | mail...`. Or even `echo | mail...` to make the body an empty line.

Comment: BTW, the syntax to read a line in ksh is `IFS= read -r line`, and to print *arbitrary* data: `print -r -- "$data"`. Without those `-r` (or with `echo`), backslash characters receive a special treatment.

Comment: @Kusanalanda: The example is very much simplified. I loop over the input file. On some strings found, I want to start something, on some strings I want to calculate something and on certain conditions I want to send a warning by email. The warning does not need much text (message body), it's enough to describe the Warning in the subject field.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas  
about syntax: Thank you for that tip. But in 20 years I always used "cat file | while read ...." without ever having a problem.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - about your solution with "echo | mail ...":   Oh WOW, It's so simple? Waht a shame that I did not found by myself. Thank you very much, your solution works absolutely perfect for me :-)

Comment: Then I take it you've never processed input containing backslashes or starting or ending with space or tabs (and wanting to preserve them) assuming an unmodified IFS or ending in a character of IFS.

Comment: Also note that the standard command (though optional) for sending email is `mailx`. `mail` is not a standard command. Some systems have one (or sometimes a `Mail` one) though not all support a `-s` option to set the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `mail` (or preferably  the standard `mailx`), when in send mode, reads the body of the email to send from stdin.

You generally don't want to send empty emails. More often than not, an empty body is a sign something went wrong which is why your `mail` command gives you  that warning.

I don't know if AIX `mail` command has a way to disable that warning (though you could discard it along with any other warning or error message with `2> /dev/null`), but alternatively, you could send a minimal body such as `See subject.` or an empty line with:

```
echo See subject. | mailx...
```

```
echo | mailx...
```

So, putting it all together:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -r strA ; do  
  printf 'strA: "%s"\n' "$strA"  
  echo | mailx -s"check script strA: $strA" me@mailserver.example.com  
done 3< infile
```

Opening `infile` on fd 3 (which contrary to 0, 1, 2 is not special), instead of fd 0 also makes sure commands in the loop won't read from it.

See also:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) for the correct syntax to read a line verbatim.
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) for why you can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data.