# reading filenames with newlines

Tags: bash, xargs, read

Now we're all familiar with not using:

```
find . -print | xargs cmd
```

but using

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 cmd
```

To cope with filenames containing e.g. newline, but what about a line I have in a script:

```
find $@ -type f -print | while read  filename
```

Well, I assumed it would be something like:

```
find $@ -type f -print0 | while read -d"\0" filename
```

And if I'd simply done:

```
 find $@ -type f -print0 | while read filename
```

I'd be seeing the NULLs?

But No, **the while loop exits after zero times around** (in both cases) I assume because the read returned zero, also I assume because it read a NULL (\0) .

Feels like the bash **read** should sport a **"-0"** option.

Have I misread what's happening or is there a different way to frame this?

For this example I may well have to recode to use xargs but that's a whole heap of new processes I didn't want to fork.

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `read`, you can use just `-d ''` to read up to the next null character.

From the `bash` manual, regarding the `read` built-in utility:

> `-d delim`
> The first character of `delim` is used to terminate the
> input line, rather than newline.  If `delim` is the empty
> string, `read` will terminate a line when it reads a NUL
> character.

You probably also want to set `IFS` to an empty string to stop `read` from trimming flanking whitespaces from the data, and to use `read` with `-r` to be able to read strings containing backslashes properly. You also need to double quote the expansion `$@` if you want your script or shell function to support search paths containing newlines, spaces, filename globbing characters, etc:

```bsh
find "$@" -type f -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' pathname; do
    # use "$pathname" to do something
done
```

Personally, I would not pass pathnames out of `find` at all if it's not desperately needed, but execute the needed operations via `-exec`, e.g.,

```bsh
find "$@" -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # use "$pathname" to do something
    done' sh {} +
```

Related topics:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

Comment: @they Thanks for that, it works , as I guess you know.

I was a little confused how it could work, so I grabbed  a copy of the bash source:


~/src/bash/bash-5.1/builtins/read.def : Line 319

 case 'd':
   delim = *list_optarg;
   break;

For the non C guys out there. Strings in C are null delimited so "foo" would be an array of char of length 4 'f','o','o','\0'  if list_optarg held this then *list_optarg would get list_optarg[0] i.e. 'f'. If you passed ''  then the array would be length of 1 and  list_optarg[0]  would be '\0' (single char holding a zero).

Comment: An earlier version of the 1st response used $'\0' (which would create 2 nuls an use the 1st one) see:

[link][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135775/meaning-of-read-and-d-and-0-in-bash?noredirect=1&lq=1][link]

I feel '$\0' aids readability ....makes it clear you're looking for NULs

Comment: @GraemeV That was an error on my part. The use of `$'\0'` is nonsensical, as it is the same as `''` in the `bash` shell. You can see that by using `echo $'\0' | hexdump -C` and comparing that with `echo '' | hexdump -C`. You will also notice that the result is the same as with `$'\0hello'`. This does not hold true for the `zsh` shell.  In my view, it is clearer with `-d ''` as that is explicitly mentioned in the manual.

Comment: BTW, the reason I use read rather than -exec or xargs. Consider, this is recursing down a tree of a million files:

**-exec** will fork off a million new processes
**xargs** will fork off several hundred thousand processes
whereas **read** will fork no additional process

Comment: While both '' and  $'\0'  obviously work , the "verbose" form stand out (looks odd) and so people are likely to see it and pause for thought. Similarly the code in bash would be clearer were it coded as:

 list_optarg[0]

Rather than

*list_optarg

Helps with self documentation.

Comment: @GraemeV Look at my `find` command at the end of my answer.  That will invoke `sh -c` for _batches_ of as many pathnames as possible at once, not once per pathname.  This is due to the `{} +` at the end (rather than `{} \;`). This is probably at least as good as `xargs` would do.  For millions of files, the overhead of launching `sh -c`, even thousands of times, is negligible. Using `{} +` is supported by the POSIX standard.

Comment: @GraemeV, I have the vague understanding that the fact `read -d ''` works like that is originally an accident due to the way C strings work and it wasn't even documented to begin with. (Well, the Bash 4.4 man page on my system doesn't document it.)