# Renaming all files in the current directory to names listed in a text file

Tags: text-processing, files, rename

The original title was: **Injecting vidir with vim like sequence of commands**

I have been trying to use vidir to rename multiple files which are accidently renamed by someone.
Problem is vidir doesnt use sorted order of files it sometimes picks randomly.
The way my files are messed up i have to rename them using ls -rt

**Problem:**
Files all randomly renamed. But i have a text file containing names of all files in ls -rt order.
Wanted to use that text file read the names and rename files in folder using `ls -rt` order

`ls -rt` output

```
cbb308e52a3345e4ff436b2f
a4b8e2aacae0a3304b3c28b8
43ca3253da336012788d3279~
ada694316cc605c7ffb790d1
3b6cc01ff2aaa5b1709918ef
7057cbda90a7adf303a56bb4~
7c0dd50bc52bb444000cc175
```

Txt_with_Names_In_Order

```
e0e87002d27674ddafdb5f7077887da6-1.ps
c7685093e84da8074859efc5783687b6-2.ps
062936279f54f4f5a541b5bee4daf5d4-3.ps
6f91bb10840a4a5a5331c832e5c2beb1-4.ps
9a8c5e9ae8b633a2a588518d2b9ab656-5.ps
bcb77709b10eafbd2fc88ce8db41ed3f-6.ps
e65c35be3c8b0aa051fb33ed2ce43ff7-7.ps
```

**Solutions:**

Now,It can be done by  loop but writing long loop command is not feasible, when vidir comes to handy very quickly.

My vim command sequence includes

```
^[ggVGg^A some regex
```

```
ls -rt | vidir -
```

Above works
But it requires interactive working.

Wanted to inject sequence like

```
ls -rt | vidir - << EOF
commands
EOF
```

OR

```
vim file << EOF sequence EOF ------> it works
command | vim - << EOF sequence of vim commands to edit input ELF ----> Want a workaround for this
```

But input seems to be conflicting.

Can anyone help if workaround is possible.

[Not want to use expect]
Can anyone help with:

how to use ^[ggVgg^A directly from command line in vim ex mode.?

**What i am trying is to pipe output of some command to vim and also inject sequence of vim commands to act on that piped input non interactively**

Comment: Scripting `vim` is not ideal. Show what you are trying to achieve and we may come up with a more efficient and rubust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request to find a solution based on `vim` or `vidir` is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

As I understand your question, the real requirement is to rename the existing files in the current directory to the names in a text file which is in `ls -rt` order.

The following solution for `bash` assumes that both the current and saved file names don't contain spaces, newlines or other problematic characters, and that the text file contains one file name per line.

```
readarray -t new < /path/to/filenames.txt ; \
i=0 ; \
ls -rt1 | while read -r old
do
    echo mv "$old" "${new[$i]}"
    ((i++))
done
```

The script above will only show the commands that would be executed. If the output matches your requirements, remove the `echo` before `mv` and run the script again to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved with shell commands (bash).
First of all backup the folder.

Create a file containing the bad names in correct order: `ls -tr > badnames.txt`
So these two files have the good and bad names with the correct order.
Merge them together:

```
paste badnames.txt TXT_with_Names_In_Order > bothnames.txt
```

and finally type:

```
while read BADNAME GOODNAME
do
mv $BADNAME $GOODNAME
done < bothnames.txt
```

This chunk of code reads one line of your bothnames.txt file, and splits it in two variables. then it uses the mv command to rename your files.

Comment: It may work with the names in question, but *in general* the solution is fragile at least because of [what `read` does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618), possible [spaces and such](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618).

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that you have a file with the old and new names per line, so you can decide if it looks correct prior to processing it.