# Unable to iterate over all files in bash in archlinux's docker container?

Tags: bash, arch-linux

I am running a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
touch archlinux_log.txt
touch packages_not_in_archlinux.txt

while read line; do    
  if pacman -Q --info $line ; then
     
      pacman -Q --info $line >> archlinux_log.txt
  else
      echo "No Package info for $line"
      $line >> packages_not_in_archlinux.txt
  fi
done<"$1"
```

However, a very peculiar problem that I am facing here is that the script always stops at a particular package name called **dirmngr** and displays the following message :

```
dirmngr[10701.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 141
dirmngr[10701.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
dirmngr[10701.0]:            trusted certificates: 141 (141,0,0,0)
```

I have ran the same script in Debian and Fedora and encountered no problems as such. All packages were scanned through. Any hints why this is happening with archlinux? Help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line in your script will execute whatever is in `$line` and append the output to `packages_not_in_archlinux.txt`:

```bash
$line >> packages_not_in_archlinux.txt
```

If `$line` expands to `dirmngr`, then that is the command that would be run at that point in the script.

You might have wanted to store the string `$line` in the output file instead:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$line" >>packages_not_in_archlinux.txt
```

The whole script, with proper quoting of variables and avoiding to run `pacman` twice:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

while IFS= read -r package; do    
    if pacman -Q --info "$package" >"$tmpfile"
    then
        cat "$tmpfile" >>archlinux_log.txt
    else
        printf 'No package info for %s\n' "$package"
        printf '%s\n' "$package" >>packages_not_in_archlinux.txt
    fi
done <"$1"

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)

Comment: Thank you very much!