# How to read multiline input in bash

Tags: bash, read

I have this script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
main() {
  while true; do 
    read -r -ep "> " input
    history -s "$input"
    echo "$input"
  done
}
main
```

which works well for single line strings.

Now I'm looking to allow the user to enter multiline strings, e.g. something like the following:

```
> foo \
> bar
foobar
```

how do I modify my read command to allow this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly *disable* the special handling of backslash with `-r`.

If you remove `-r` from your `read` invocation, you will be able to read your input with the escaped newline:

```bash
$ read input
hello \
> world
$ echo "$input"
hello world
```

Compare that with what happens if you use `-r` (which is *usually* what you want to do):

```bash
$ read -r input
hello \
$ echo "$input"
hello \
```

Note that without `-r`, you will have to enter `\\` to read a single backslash.

Related:

- [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)