# sed with while read misses line

Tags: bash, sed

Can someone please explain this?

I have a file:

```
cat listi.txt
sdfasdfsf123sadfasdf123
jlkjh2345ljkh245lkh4325
57hghf456ghf457gf467
```

Here sed misses the first line:

```
while read line ; do sed 's/[^0-9]//g'; done < listi.txt 

23452454325
57456457467
```

Seen here:

```
while read line ; do echo $line; done < listi.txt 

sdfasdfsf123sadfasdf123
jlkjh2345ljkh245lkh4325
57hghf456ghf457gf467
```

This works but feels redundant and I could have missed it because I assumed sed would deliver all lines:

```
while read line ; do echo $line | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'; done < listi.txt 

123123
23452454325
57456457467
```

Why is this? Regain my trust in bash as this makes me skeptic

Comment: You read one line, you do _nothing_ with it, then `sed` consumes/processes the remaining two lines. That's all. The proper way to do it is `sed 's/[^0-9]//g' listi.txt` , you don't need `while..read`

Comment: what's the point of the `while read line` to begin with?

Comment: @ilkkachu Conceptually, they would read a line, process it, and then output it. It's common to see code like this from users that are not fully familiar with "the Unix way" of using the provided tools as filters, and that may be more familiar with scripting languages like Python or Perl, etc.

Comment: This was a dummy example, I was working with multiple files so I thought of using 'while read' ... my bad, it was irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Writing a buggy one-liner is scarcely a valid reason to lose trust in Bash.

Comment: A sleepless idiot with vibrating arteries full of coffee loses trust in anything buggy, self-inflicted or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial loop:

```bash
while read line; do
    sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
done <listi.txt
```

What happens here is that the `read` reads one line from the loop's input stream, which comes from the `listi.txt` file. The value is stored into the variable `line` ([with some caveats](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123)) and not further used.

The call to `sed` is then done without mentioning an input file, which means `sed` will read from its standard input stream.

The standard input stream of `sed` is inherited from the loop, so it reads and processes the second line from `listi.txt` along with all other lines until the end of the file is reached.

The loop then executes `read` again, but since there's nothing more to read, the call fails and the loop terminates.

The overall effect of the above is that the first line of the file `listi.txt` is ignored, while `sed` is processing the file from the second line onward, removing non-digits from each of these and outputting them to the terminal.

If you simply want to apply the `sed` expression to all lines in `listi.txt`, you would use

```bash
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' listi.txt
```

That is, there is no need to use a separate shell loop since `sed` will apply its editing expression(s) to each line in the input file(s) by default.

If what you want to do is to delete all non-digits, then you may also do that with `tr`, which is a tool that does single character transformations:

```bash
tr -d -c '0-9\n' <listi.txt
```

This deletes (`-d`) any character from the input that is part of the complement (`-c`) of the mentioned set of characters (`0-9\n`; we probably want to keep the newline characters that divide the input into lines, which is why that is included here).  The `0-9\n` bit could also be written `[:digit:]\n`, which would match any digit in the current locale, and the newline character.

Also related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Comment: So while..read could be a 'worst practice' way of skipping the header, a common issue

Comment: @AWE To skip the first line, yes, but that is more commonly done with `tail -n +2` or `sed 1d`. Note that a "header" could contain newline characters and thus spread multiple lines, if it's a file in a structured document format such as CSV.

Comment: @AWE, a worst practice indeed, since the loop doesn't do anything there. A slightly less bad one would be something like `(read x; sed ... ) < file`. But yeah, using `tail` or doing it in `sed` would be better, esp. as you can do e.g. `sed -e 1d -e 's/[^0-9]//g' < file` in one command