# How to sort the list of positional parameters in POSIX sh

Tags: shell-script, shell, sort, posix, array

Is there a way to sort the list of positional parameters in POSIX sh? Each positional parameter could contain arbitrary characters (e.g. spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.). The sort algorithm should be general enough to sort the list based on any comparison defined by the programmer (e.g. numeric/lexicographical sorting using [`expr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html) comparison, sorting that considers only a substring of each positional parameter, etc.).

It seems that POSIX sh's list of positional arguments has the characteristics of both a stack and a queue.  It supports push (`set -- "$x" "$@"`), pop (`x="$1"; shift`), enqueue (`set -- "$@" "$x"`) and dequeue (`x="$1"; shift`) operations. However, there can only be a single list, which means that sorting must be done in-place and I cannot use common algorithms such as merge sort and quicksort.

Sample:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- "Hello" "world" 9 8 7 "$(printf "0\n1")" "$(printf "1\t2")"

# How do I sort the positional parameters above using comparison
# `expr "$x" \< "$y"` such that the result is the list below?
#
# "$(printf "0\n1")" "$(printf "1\t2")" 9 8 7 "Hello" "world"
```

Note 1: I am looking for a POSIX solution that works for arbitrary positional arguments supplied by a user and arbitrary comparisons specified by the programmer.

Note 2: I am not trying to solve any practical problem. I have challenged myself to this `sh` sorting problem but I could not come up with a solution, so I am posting it here on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I assume clunky workarounds like printing to a temp file, then using `sort` and reading the file are not what you're after, right?

Comment: Note that your "pop" and "dequeue" operations are the same. There's no reasonable way remove an element off the end of the list. (In Bash, you could do `set -- "${@:1: $#-1}"`, but it's not POSIX and will croak if the list if empty to begin with.) This is probably one of those things that would be better done in another programming language with better support for data structures.

Comment: That is to say, POSIX sh only allows indexing into the list of positional parameters for getting the values, but you can't assign values in the middle, and you can't remove them from the middle. Any algorithm that involves swapping list items is pretty much impossible to use. You could swap the first two with something like `x=$1 y=$2; shift; shift; set -- "$y" "$x" "$@"`, though, but generalizing that to an arbitrary pair, or even an arbitrary consecutive pair gets rather difficult.

Comment: You could move the values to variables called `e1`, `e2` etc. and do `eval` tricks to "index" that, but that way lies madness. You can't really even shove the values to an outside program (like `sort`), since to be able to hold arbitrary values, you'd need to read NUL-separated output back from the program, and that's not really easy POSIXly.

Answer (score 3):

Probably easiest is to resort to `awk` which can do `strcoll()`, `strcmp()`, and number comparisons (including of floating points).

To avoid reinventing the wheel, we can use the quicksort awk implementation at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#AWK (GPLv2).

Then use (**Edit**: see further down for a better, safer approach):

```
code=$(
  awk -v q="'" -- '
    code-from-that-link-above
    BEGIN {
      delete ARGV[0]
      n = qsortArbIndByValue(ARGV, sorted)
      printf "set --"
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        s = ARGV[sorted[i]]
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
        printf " %s", q s q
      }
    }' "$@"
) || exit
eval "$code"
```

That assumes the positional parameters contain valid text in the user's locale and that the list is small enough to fit in command line arguments (and in awk's array size limit).

That uses `awk`'s `<` operator which will do number comparison if operands are recognised as numbers or `strcoll()` comparison otherwise. You can force `strcoll()` comparison by changing the comparisons from `a < b` to `a"" < b""` (fix the locale to C for `strcmp()` comparison) and force number comparison by changing to `a+0 < b+0` (`+a < +b` would also be POSIX but in practice not portable), or you can always write a custom `compare()` awk function to do whatever comparison you want.

Note that to be POSIX compliant, that code should have `gsub(q, q "\\\\" q q, s)` instead of `gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)`, however the latter, even though yielding unspecified behaviour by POSIX is more portable as the former doesn't work properly with `gawk` unless `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment nor busybox `awk` for instance.

If the data is not guaranteed to be valid text in the user's locale, one can set the locale to `C` and then the strings will be considered as arrays of bytes and sorted as if by `strcmp()` (on ASCII-based systems), not as per the user's locale collation order.

Giving `eval` something that is potentially the result of unspecified behaviour is quite uncomfortable, but on second thought, it should be possible to make it reliable if instead of having `awk` output something like `set -- '3rd argument hoped to be quoted correctly' 'first' 'second'`, we have it output `set -- "${3}" "${1}" "${2}"`.

That should also be easier to do, shorter and more efficient:

```
code=$(
  awk -- '
    code-from-that-link-above
    BEGIN {
      delete ARGV[0]
      n = qsortArbIndByValue(ARGV, sorted)
      printf "set --"
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        printf " \"${%s}\"", sorted[i]
    }' "$@"
) || exit
eval "$code"
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the shell to `eval` these string first, and then can sort the results, applying the same operations to the strings that get sorted, and the array of original indices. I'll illustrate below.

You could certainly implement your own sorting algorithm in shell script. Because the language is so badly suited for data structures/algorithms like that, it probably won't make much sense to aim for anything more complex (and theoretically less inefficient) than *Bubble Sort*. It'd be fairly short, ugly and hilarious.

1. original array as given in your question.
2. get the length of the array, and use `seq` to generate an array 1, 2, …, N
3. make a new array of identical length let the shell evaluate every entry of your original entry (so that `$(printf "0 \n"` becomes `0 \n`). This is what we'll actually need to sort
4. implement bubble sort:

   1. compare the first element to the second. If the first is larger, according to your sorting criterion (which I'm not sure about, you're a bit muddy on that), then swap (using a temporary variable) the two values, as well as the two indices in the same position
   2. continue to compare the second and third; repeat the rule above; rinse and repeat for each pair of values in sequence.
   3. after doing the comparison (and swapping) of the next-to-last with the last element, start from the beginning again (you can stop comparing one element earlier than in the previous run)
   4. at some point, you've got everything sorted. Stop!
5. using the reordered index array, you now construct the reordered array containing the original (uninterpreted) values.

Comment: how do you create another array to hold the indexes when POSIX sh only has the list of positional parameters to play with?

Comment: different ways I considered, one that I liked was to keep the indices in a tab-separated string `indices`, the index into that string in a local variable `start`, and then use `printf '%s\n'  indices | cut -f -${start},$((start+2)),$((start+1)),$((start+3))-` to get the elements before the potentially swapped, then the formerly second, now first element, the the formerly first, now second element, then the rest of the sequence; then increase `start`. (not sure whether POSIX sh does `$(( ))`, might need a temporary variable to build that fields selector)

Comment: The trick is that unlike the arguments that need to be sorted, indices are pretty restricted in valid characters, so we can throw `cut` at them.

Comment: and how to keep both the original and the evaluated argument list around: do the evaluation and sorting in a separate shell process, and print only the permuted index vector, which the "outer" shell uses.

Comment: (Frankly, POSIX specifies a little program called `c99`; I'm told that is turing-complete…)

Comment: `cut` doesn't reorder the fields, though (`printf '%s\t' a b c | cut -f 3,1` prints `a\tc`). But ok, sure you can do shenanigans like that. I'm still going to say it's insane. :) `c99` would help, for sure.

Comment: Insane? Maybe. Totally useless in practice? 100%!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

- In `sh`, escape all newline and backslash characters in each positional parameter, so that we could use the newline character as delimiter.
- Pipe the newline-separated positional parameters to `awk`.
- In `awk`, use quicksort to sort the parameters and write the newline-separated sorted parameters to standard output.
- In `sh`, replace the unsorted list of positional parameters with the newline-separated sorted parameters from `awk` by splitting on newlines.
- Unescape all newline and backslash characters in the list of sorted positional parameters.

Implementation:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Run this shell script to sort this list of positional parameters:
set -- \
    'Hello' \
    '  0  1  ' \
    '' \
    '*' \
    '\0150\0151' \
    "$(printf '\a\b\e\f\n\r\t\v')" \
    '\a\b\e\f\n\r\t\v%%\\' \
    'qwerty
uiop' \
    '

new

lines

'

printf '====== NOT YET SORTED ======\n'
for param; do
    printf '%s' "$param" | od -ab
done

quicksort() {
    for param; do
        # * Escape newlines (newline -> "\n" [two characters]).
        #   Rationale:
        #   * To be able to use newline as AWK record separator.
        #   * To be able to use it as the shell's $IFS for separating records.
        # * Escape backslashes (backslash -> "\\" [two characters]).
        #   Rationale:
        #   * To distinguish between escaped newlines and the two-character
        #     string "\n" (escaped version: "\\n" [three-character string]).
        #   * To avoid special interpretation of backslashes when passed to
        #     `printf '%b' ...`.
        #
        # `sed` solution adapted from:
        # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761885/how-to-convert-all-newlines-to-n-in-posix-sh-strings
        printf '%s\n' "$param" | LC_ALL=C sed '
            :1
            $ ! {
                N
                b1
            }
            s/\\/\\\\/g
            s/\n/\\n/g'
    done | awk -f ./quicksort.awk
}

# Create temporary file.
tmpfile="$(printf 'mkstemp(template)' \
    | m4 -D template="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/XXXXXX")" || exit 1
exec 3>"$tmpfile" 4<"$tmpfile"  # Open tmpfile for writing and reading.
rm -f -- "$tmpfile"

quicksort "$@" >&3 3>&-

set --
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # Unescape backslashes and newlines.
    # To preserve trailing newlines (if any), insert a trailing character 'x'
    # and later remove it.
    elem="$(printf '%bx' "$line")"
    set -- "$@" "${elem%x}"
done <&4 4<&-

printf '\n====== SORTED RESULTS ======\n'
for param; do
    printf '%s' "$param" | od -ab
done
```

This is `quicksort.awk`:

```c
# Takes newline-separated records from standard input and sorts them according
# to the `compare` function. Outputs the sorted newline-separated records to
# standard output.
#
# Backslash and newline characters supplied within each input record must be
# escaped like this:
# * backslash character -> "\\" (two backslash characters)
# * newline character -> "\n" (backslash character followed by the "n" character)
#
# Backslash and newline characters within each output record will be escaped in
# the same manner.
#
# Usage: awk -f quicksort.awk
#
# Attribution:
# Functions `quicksort` and `quicksort_swap` are adapted from the public domain
# quicksort implementation by Arnold Robbins retrieved from
# https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awklib/eg/lib/quicksort.awk?h=gawk-5.3.0

function compare(a, b) {
    # Unescape backslashes and newlines.
    gsub(/\\/, "\\", a)
    gsub(/\\/, "\\", b)
    gsub(/\\n/, "\n", a)
    gsub(/\\n/, "\n", b)

    # For sorting in ascending lexicographic order.
    return a < b
}

function quicksort(data, left, right,    i, last) {
    if (left >= right)  # Do nothing if array contains fewer than two elements.
        return

    quicksort_swap(data, left, int((left + right) / 2))
    last = left
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        if (compare(data[i], data[left]))
            quicksort_swap(data, ++last, i)
    quicksort_swap(data, left, last)
    quicksort(data, left, last - 1, less_than)
    quicksort(data, last + 1, right, less_than)
}

function quicksort_swap(data, i, j,    temp) {
    temp = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]
    data[j] = temp
}

{
    lines[counter++] = $0
}

END {
    quicksort(lines, 0, counter - 1)
    for (k = 0; k < counter; k++)
        print lines[k]
}
```

Tested in:

- Debian 12, Dash 0.5.12, GNU sed 4.9, Gawk 5.2.1
- Debian 12, Dash 0.5.12, Busybox 1.35.0's `sed` and `awk`
- FreeBSD 13.2's `sh`, `sed`, and `awk`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have edited the shell script to fix the issues that arise when the positional parameters is `set '*'` or `set a '' b`. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Note that setting IFS to newline for read doesn't make much sense since `read` only reads one line at a time, so there will never be any newline in it to split on. To read a line, the idiomatic syntax is `IFS= read -r line`. See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: If you set `LC_ALL=C` for `sed`, then you need to set it for `awk` as well, but then it will affect the string collation order. In the C locale, every byte is treated as a character. While in the user's locale in text utilities such as sed or awk (not `printf`), byte sequences  are meant to be decoded into characters. In some locales, there are some characters whose encoding contains the encoding of backslash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Fixed the `IFS` issue. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Regarding the `LC_ALL=C` for `sed`: is it a good idea to remove `LC_ALL=C` and leave the choice of `LC_ALL` to the programmer/user?

Comment: Well with `printf` working at byte level, it's only guaranteed to work properly in the C locale (in practice that should also work OK in other single byte locales and in UTF-8 provided the strings are properly UTF-8 encoded). BTW, see the update to my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an insertion sort in POSIX sh:

```bash
sort ()
{
    f=false
    for x
    do
        if ! $f
        then
            set -- "$1"
            f=true
        else
            q=false
            # marginally faster than while + "$1" in my tests
            for y
            do
                if $q || "$cmp" "$x" "$y"
                then
                    set -- "$@" "$y"
                else
                    set -- "$@" "$x" "$y"
                    q=true
                fi
                shift
            done
            $q || set -- "$@" "$x"
        fi
    done
    "$cont" "$@"
}

islonger ()
{
    [ ${#1} -gt ${#2} ]
}

puts ()
{
    printf %s\\n "$@"
}

cmp=islonger
cont=puts
sort "$@"
```

While not a pinnacle of efficiency, on my machine bash runs it fast enough to be useful on really small inputs:

```
$ shuf /usr/share/dict/words | head -n 50 | xargs -d '\n' sh -c 'time sh sort.sh "$@"' sh
sic
alto
Biko
needs
Capet
scuba
bowed
sicks
waxier
Kodaly
Tuvalu
hubbub
Gide's
panache
Joann's
peeling
mermaid
wingnut
savvies
crybaby
Python's
nitwit's
junction
tailored
tussocks
rotaries
Brandi's
leafiest
banknote
Spence's
Heriberto
prepaying
telephony
indelible
addendum's
stampeding
hatchway's
pathogenic
Englishman
escarole's
outstaying
synonymous
Youngstown
rebroadcast
overstuffed
interweaves
deliquescent
grandmothers
Cryptozoic's
mammography's

real    0m0.039s
user    0m0.038s
sys     0m0.001s
```

I believe many sorting algorithms can be implemented reasonably straightforwardly in POSIX shell.  The biggest pain point is the non-existent swap operation.  Of course, if you are willing to do things like serialization and `eval`, everything is possible.

Here is a merge sort using the same principles:

```bash
sort ()
{
    n=1
    while [ $n -lt $# ]
    do
        h=0
        k=$n
        l=$n
        while [ $h -lt $# ]
        do
            i=0
            j=0
            if [ $(($# - h)) -lt $((n << 1)) ]
            then
                if [ $(($# - h)) -le $n ]
                then
                    k=$(($# - h))
                    l=0
                else
                    l=$(($# % n))
                fi
            fi
            for x
            do
                [ $i -eq 0 ] && shift $k
                while [ $j -lt $l ]
                do
                    if [ $i -eq $k ] || "$cmp" "$x" "$1"
                    then
                        set -- "$@" "$1"
                        shift
                        j=$((j + 1))
                    else
                        break
                    fi
                done
                [ $i -eq $k ] && break
                set -- "$@" "$x"
                i=$((i + 1))
            done
            h=$((h + (n << 1)))
        done
        n=$((n << 1))
    done
    "$cont" "$@"
}
```

```
$ shuf /usr/share/dict/words | head -n 1000 | xargs -d '\n' sh -c 'time sh sort.sh "$@"' sh >/dev/null
 
real    0m19.918s
user    0m19.917s
sys     0m0.001s
```