# How to convert all newlines to "\n" in POSIX sh strings

Tags: shell-script, shell, string, posix, escape-characters

I have a string that contains newline characters. I want to escape all newlines in that string by replacing all newline characters with a string of two characters: "\n". How can I do this in POSIX sh?

Here's the goal:

```bash
$ printf 'a\nb\nc\nd' | escape_newlines | od -a
0000000   a   \   n   b   \   n   c   \   n   d
        141 134 156 142 134 156 143 134 156 144
0000012
```

How do I define `escape_newlines`?

Methods I have tried:

- `tr` — Problem: not able to convert single character into multiple characters.
- `awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"} {print}'` — Problem: always inserts the two-character string "\n" at the end of the string even if the string does not end with a newline character. Example:

  ```bash
  $ printf 'hi\n' | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"} {print}' | od -ab
  0000000   h   i   \   n
          150 151 134 156
  0000004
  $ printf 'hi' | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"} {print}' | od -ab
  0000000   h   i   \   n
          150 151 134 156
  0000004
  ```
- `sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/\\n/g'` — Problem: if there is a newline character at the end of the string, it will not be converted. Example:

  ```bash
  $ printf 'h\ni' | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/\\n/g' | od -ab
  0000000   h   \   n   i
          150 134 156 151
  0000004
  $ printf 'h\ni\n' | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/\\n/g' | od -ab
  0000000   h   \   n   i  nl
          150 134 156 151 012
  0000005
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `awk` with:

```
string='x
y
'
new_string=$(
  LC_ALL=C awk -- '
    BEGIN {
      gsub("\n", "\\n", ARGV[1])
      printf "%s", ARGV[1]
    }' "$string"
)
```

In any case, note that command substitution removes all trailing newline characters. OK here as the output of `awk` doesn't contain any, but that means we could also have used `print` instead of `printf "%s"`.

With `sed`:

```
new_string=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$string" |
    LC_ALL=C sed '
      :1
      $ ! {
        N
        b1
      }
      s/\n/\\n/g'
)
```

Note that per POSIX, using `N` on the last line is meant to discard the pattern space and exit. GNU `sed` only does it when `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment, but still exits upon `N` called on the last line (but still prints the pattern space).

We use `LC_ALL=C` to avoid potential issues with decoding the string in the charmap of the user's locale.

`sed` is a text utility, so it expects text input and produces text output. Something that is not empty and doesn't end in a newline character is not text. Here we add one newline to the input, and rely on command substitution to remove the one `sed` adds on output.

Also note that if the input has lines with a length in bytes larger than LINE_MAX (which can be as low as 1024), that makes it non-text as well, and the behaviour is unspecified. IIRC, the pattern space is not required to be able to hold more than 10 x LINE_MAX as well.

The `awk` approach will have some limits as well starting with ARG_MAX which on systems will be lower than 10 x LINE_MAX. That limit applies to the `sed` one as well with shells where `printf` is not builtin (such as ksh88 or pdksh-based ones).

There's no limit to the size of a shell variable, though if it's exported to the environment, it will run against the ARG_MAX limit for all the external commands that are executed.

To process a stream, you'd need something like:

```
... | (cat; echo) | LC_ALL=C awk '
  {printf "%s", sep $0; sep = "\\n"}'
```

Though beware that output is not text so cannot be processed by a POSIX text utility.

Comment: How do I use the `awk` solution in a pipeline as shown in the `escape_newlines` example goal in the question?

Comment: @Flux, see edit.