# How to resolve the issue of the echo (with >>) eating up the line indendations?

Tags: io-redirection, echo, indentation

Consider the below commands typed into the terminal:

```
$ ls
my-file.js prefix.yml

$ cat prefix.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: file1-cm
  namespace: default
data:
  my-file.js: |

$ #kindly note the line feeds in the above output
$ cat my-file.js
let a = require('a');
let b = require('b');

module.exports = function(app, cb) {
    console.log(a + b);
}

$ #kindly note the line feeds and indentation
$ cat prefix.yml > file1-cm.yaml; cat my-file.js | while read LINE; do echo "  ${LINE}" >> file1-cm.yaml; done; echo done;
done
$ cat file1-cm.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: file1-cm
  namespace: default
data:
  my-file.js: |
  let a = require('a');
  let b = require('b');

  module.exports = function(app, cb) {
  console.log(a + b);
  cb();
  }
```

I was expecting a relative indentation in `file1-cm.yaml` file to be equivalent to the indentation `my-file.js`. Am I missing something in the apis of `echo` or `read`? How come `cat my-file.js` preserve the indendations whereas `echo` does not?

Comment: `read` with the default `IFS` will remove leading whitespace - see for example [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)